# Is there a built in way to identify instances of a class?

Tags: c#, .net, class, instance

I am doing some diagnostic logging with one of my C#.NET projects and I would like to be able to log an identifier that represents a specific instance of a class. I know I could do this with a static variable that just gets incremented every time a class instance is created but I am just wondering if there is any built-in way in the .NET framework to do this. Maybe using reflection or something.

Comment: The discussion at this question may help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750947/net-unique-object-identifier

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just to add to what [Henk said in his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3569776/is-there-a-built-in-way-to-identify-instances-of-a-class/3569800#3569800) about `GetHashCode`, and to mitigate some of the negative comments he received on that answer:

There is a way to call `GetHashCode` on **any** object that is independent of that object's value, regardless of whether or not its type has overridden `GetHashCode`.

Take a look at [`System.Runtime.CompilerServices.RuntimeHelpers.GetHashCode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/11tbk3h9.aspx).

This value is not guaranteed to be unique, of course. Neither is a `Guid` (though for that *not* to be unique would involve odds that are legitimately microscopic).

I'd say your gut was right about the static counter variable. I should mention, though, that simply incrementing it using the `++` operator in each object's constructor is not thread-safe. If it's possible you could be instantiating instances of a class from multiple threads you would want to use [`Interlocked.Increment`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd78zt0c.aspx) instead.

Answer (score 9):

You could add a `Guid` property to your class an initialize it in the constructor (guaranteed unique for each instance).

Comment: Used this technique a few times. You can just directly initialize a field `public Guid InstanceId = Guid.NewGuid();` to keep your constructor clean of debugging stuff.

Comment: That is not much easier or any more convenient than using a static counter. It is a lot harder on the eyes.

Comment: How would you use a static counter? It will be the same in each instance since it is static. Am I mistaken?

Comment: @Zebi - `static int s_counter = 0;` and then `int id = s_counter++;`. Each object will be sequentially numbered with no repeats.

Comment: @Zebi, @Henk - Using a `Guid` is only a tiny bit easier, but as Henk said, it's harder to read. The only advantage here is that a `Guid` is unique across all objects, not just instances of the same class. Of course, you could create a static counter for that, too, if you really wanted to.

Comment: @Henk's solution is probably the easiest, even though it's not "technically" perfect. I only posted this before I understood he meant to use the default `GetHashcode()` behavior.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe `Object.ReferenceEquals` solves your problem. At least it can tell you if an object is the same as some other.

You can not use a static variable because it will be the same in each instance. It will just have the count of the objects created.

You have the possibility to use Jon B's solution or if you want numeric identifiers use a static counter and assign an id to a field.

```
public class Foo
{
    static int counter;
    public int InstanceId;

    public Foo()
    {
        InstanceId = counter++;
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure what you describe in your last part is exactly what the OP meant by "static variable" (that would be `counter`).