# How do I obtain an ID that allows me to tell difference instances of a class apart?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

Imagine I have a single class, with two instances:

```
MyClass a = new MyClass();
MyClass b = new MyClass();
```

MyClass has a method PrintUniqueInstanceID:

```
void PrintUniqueInstanceID()
{
  Console.Write("Unique ID for the *instance* of this class: {0}", 
      [what goes here???]
  );
}
```

Ideally, the output would be something like:

```
Unique ID for the *instance* of this class: 23439434        // from a.PrintUniqueInstanceID
Unique ID for the *instance* of this class: 89654           // from b.PrintUniqueInstanceID
```

So - what would I insert in "`[what goes here???]`", above, which prints a unique number for every unique instance of the class?

**Ideas**

1. Perhaps cast "this" to an int pointer, and use that?
2. Use GCHandle somehow?
3. Access a property of "this", within the method, to uniquely identify it?

**(optional) Background Information For Experts**

The reason I need this is that I am using AOP and PostSharp to automatically detect threading issues. I need to look up each unique instance of the class in a dictionary, in order to verify that multiple threads are not accessing the same unique instance of a class (its ok if there is one thread per class instance).

**Update**

As others have pointed out, I should mention that I can't touch any of the existing classes in the 30,000 line project. PrintUniqueInstanceID, above, is an aspect (see [PostSharp](http://www.sharpcrafters.com/)) that is added to the top level class, is inherited by every class in the entire project, and executes on every method entry in the entire project.

Once I have verified that everything is thread safe, I'll remove the aspect to restore performance.

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750947/net-unique-object-identifier

Comment: As far as I know, the objects a and b only differ in their position in memory. So what could be working is to create a pointer to that object and see its address. I'm just guessing, not sure if this works as I said.

Comment: You state that `PrintUniqueInstanceID` is a _member_ of `MyClass` that needs to be changed, but you keep telling answerers that you can't change the "existing class". So which is it?

Comment: @jmh_gr PrintUniqueInstanceID is an aspect that is automatically executed on every entry to every method of the class. So, it is a member of the class, in a sense - but it is added in a post-compile step by PostSharp. I can't alter 30,000 lines of code by changing all of the classes in the entire project, but I can very easily add an temporary aspect to the top level class, which is automatically inherited by every method in the entire project. Once I have verified everything is thread safe, I can remove it.

Comment: Can you not just store the object ref itself in your dictionary, or do you need the unique id for some other reason?

Comment: @LukeH Good thinking - and that's exactly what I've already tried. However, a dictionary with "this" as its key doesn't generate a unique entry for each class instance, it only generates a unique entry for each class type, which leave us back at square one. I've added a couple of potential answers below.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use ObjectIDGenerator class:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.objectidgenerator.aspx

Quote:

> The IDs are unique for the life of the ObjectIDGenerator instance.
>
> Using a hash table, the ObjectIDGenerator retains which ID is assigned
>   to which object. The object references, which uniquely identify each
>   object, are addresses in the runtime garbage-collected heap. Object
>   reference values can change during serialization, but the table is
>   updated automatically so the information is correct.
>
> Object IDs are 64-bit numbers. Allocation starts from one, so zero is
>   never a valid object ID. A formatter can choose a zero value to
>   represent an object reference whose value is null.

**Update**

This is the code that solves the problem. In the aspect class, use the following:

```
public static ObjectIDGenerator ObjectIDGen = new ObjectIDGenerator();
```

then:

```
bool firstTime;
long classInstanceID = ObjectIDGenerator.GetId(args.Instance, out firstTime);
```

**Update**

Thought I'd post the code that this entire post is based on. This code helps to detect thread safety hotspots across an entire project, by triggering warnings if multiple threads access the same instance of a class.

Useful if you have 30k lines of existing code, and you want to add a more formal verification of thread safety (something which is extremely difficult to do normally). It does impact runtime performance, so you can remove it after running it for a few days in debug mode.

To use, add PostSharp + this class to your project, then add an aspect "[MyThreadSafety]" to any class. PostSharp will insert the code in "OnEntry" before every method call. The aspect propagates to all sub-classes and sub-methods, so you can add thread safety checks to an entire project with just one line of code.

For another example of this technique in action, see an [example designed to easily add caching to method calls](http://www.sharpcrafters.com/blog/post/solid-caching.aspx).

```
    using System;
    using System.Diagnostics;
    using System.Reflection;
    using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
    using System.Runtime.Serialization;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading;
    using MyLogType;
    using PostSharp.Aspects;
    using System.Collections.Concurrent;
    using PostSharp.Extensibility;

    namespace Demo
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Example code based on the page from a Google search of:
        /// postsharp "Example: Tracing Method Execution"
        /// </summary>
        [Serializable]
        public sealed class MyThreadSafetyCheck : OnMethodBoundaryAspect
        {
            /// <summary>
            /// We need to be able to track if a different ThreadID is seen when executing a method within the *same* instance of a class. Its
            /// ok if we see different ThreadID values when accessing different instances of a class. In fact, creating one copy of a class per
            /// thread is a reliable method to fix threading issues in the first place.
            /// 
            /// Key: unique ID for every instance of every class.
            /// Value: LastThreadID, tracks the ID of the last thread which accessed the current instance of this class.
            /// </summary>
            public static ConcurrentDictionary<long, int> DetectThreadingIssues = new ConcurrentDictionary<long, int>();

            /// <summary>
            /// Allows us to generate a unique ID for each instance of every class that we see.
            /// </summary>
            public static ObjectIDGenerator ObjectIDGenerator = new ObjectIDGenerator();

            /// <summary>
            /// These fields are initialized at runtime. They do not need to be serialized.
            /// </summary>
            [NonSerialized]
            private string MethodName;

            [NonSerialized]
            private long LastTotalMilliseconds;

            /// <summary>
            /// Stopwatch which we can use to avoid swamping the log with too many messages for threading violations.
            /// </summary>
            [NonSerialized]
            private Stopwatch sw;

            /// <summary>
            /// Invoked only once at runtime from the static constructor of type declaring the target method. 
            /// </summary>
            /// <param name="method"></param>
            public override void RuntimeInitialize(MethodBase method)
            {
                if (method.DeclaringType != null)
                {
                    this.MethodName = method.DeclaringType.FullName + "." + method.Name;
                }

                this.sw = new Stopwatch();
                this.sw.Start();

                this.LastTotalMilliseconds = -1000000;
            }

            /// <summary>
            /// Invoked at runtime before that target method is invoked.
            /// </summary>
            /// <param name="args">Arguments to the function.</param>   
            public override void OnEntry(MethodExecutionArgs args)
            {
                if (args.Instance == null)
                {
                    return;
                }

                if (this.MethodName.Contains(".ctor"))
                {
                    // Ignore the thread that accesses the constructor.
                    // If we remove this check, then we get a false positive.
                    return;
                }

                bool firstTime;
                long classInstanceID = ObjectIDGenerator.GetId(args.Instance, out firstTime);

                if (firstTime)
                {
                    // This the first time we have called this, there is no LastThreadID. Return.
                    if (DetectThreadingIssues.TryAdd(classInstanceID, Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId) == false)
                    {
                        Console.Write(string.Format("{0}Error E20120320-1349. Could not add an initial key to the \"DetectThreadingIssues\" dictionary.\n",
                            MyLog.NPrefix()));
                    }
                    return;
                }

                int lastThreadID = DetectThreadingIssues[classInstanceID];

                // Check 1: Continue if this instance of the class was accessed by a different thread (which is definitely bad).
                if (lastThreadID != Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId)
                {
                    // Check 2: Are we printing more than one message per second?
                    if ((sw.ElapsedMilliseconds - this.LastTotalMilliseconds) > 1000)
                    {
                        Console.Write(string.Format("{0}Warning: ThreadID {1} then {2} accessed \"{3}\". To remove warning, manually check thread safety, then add \"[MyThreadSafetyCheck(AttributeExclude = true)]\".\n",
                            MyLog.NPrefix(), lastThreadID, Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId, this.MethodName));
                        this.LastTotalMilliseconds = sw.ElapsedMilliseconds;
                    }
                }

                // Update the value of "LastThreadID" for this particular instance of the class.
                DetectThreadingIssues[classInstanceID] = Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId;
            }
        }
    }
```

I can provide the full demo project on demand.

Comment: As explained in your comments, all this is done for checking "thread safety". But it looks to me this is introducing a thread safety issue on its own: `ObjectIDGenerator.GetId` is not guaranteed to be thread safe! `ConditionalWeakTable` from [Jon's answer](/a/9788721/1178314) is thread safe, so it looks better. (Especially since it has the additional benefit of not preventing garbage collection of objects.)

Answer (score 18):

Add a Guid property to your class, then in the constructor of the class assign it to NewGuid().

```
public class MyClass
{
    public Guid InstanceID {get; private set;}
    // Other properties, etc.

    public MyClass()
    {
        this.InstanceID = Guid.NewGuid();
    }

    void PrintUniqueInstanceID() 
    {   
        Console.Write("Unique ID for the *instance* of this class: {0}", this.InstanceID); 
    } 
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! However, this would only work if I wanted to change every class in my entire 30,000 line project. I need some method to uniquely identify the class instance within an OnEntry aspect, without altering the original class itself.

Comment: I would make the setter private. Why would you allow to change the Guid for an instance?

Comment: @Gravitas OK, your question did not specify this requirement.

Comment: @Gravitas Aren't you already changing `PrintUniqueInstanceID` in "Every class"?

Comment: @BrianRasmussen - agreed! Updated.

Comment: @jmh_gr I'm actually using PostSharp and Aspect Oriented Programming (AOP) to auto-insert C# code before the class is executed. All I do is add an attribute to the entire class, and it inserts C# code that is auto-executed before every method entry. See http://www.sharpcrafters.com/blog/post/solid-caching.aspx for an example that deals with caching (not threading), and see my answer below for the exact source code that deals with threading.

Comment: Use [Read-only auto-properties and Auto-property initializers in C# 6](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-6) and skip the constructor altogether - `public Guid InstanceID {get;} = Guid.NewGuid();`

Comment: @Pang C# 6.0 was released about 2 years after I answered the question (VS 2015), so it wasn't really an option at the time.

Answer (score 16):

### Revised answer

Based on the additional information we now have, I believe that you can solve your problem very easily using [`ConditionalWeakTable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287757.aspx) (which is *only from .NET 4 onwards*).

- it can be used to associate arbitrary data with managed object instances
- it does *not* keep objects "alive" just because they have been entered as keys into the table
- it uses *reference equality* to determine object identity; moveover, class authors *cannot* modify this behavior (handy since you are not the author of every class on earth)
- it can be populated on the fly

You can therefore create such a global table inside your "manager" class and associate each object with a `long`, a `Guid` or anything else you might want¹. Whenever your manager encounters an object it can get its associated id (if you have seen it before) or add it to the table and associate it with a new id created on the spot.

¹ *Actually the values in the table must be of a reference type, so you cannot use e.g. `long` as the value type directly. However, a simple workaround is to use `object` instead and let the `long` values be boxed.*

### Original answer

Isn't this a basic usage example for `static` members?

```
class Foo
{
    private static int instanceCounter;
    private readonly int instanceId;

    Foo()
    {
        this.instanceId = ++instanceCounter;
    }

    public int UniqueId
    {
        get { return this.instanceId; }
    }
}
```

Of course you have to pay attention to the range of identifiers so that you don't start reusing them if billions of instances are created, but that's easy to solve.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, this would only work if I wanted to change every class in my entire 30,000 line project. I need some method to uniquely identify the class instance within an OnEntry aspect, without altering the original class itself. I think that the answer might be something to do with using GCHandle to get a handle to the current class.

Comment: @Gravitas: Well, not touching existing classes is kind of an important detail that you could have mentioned earlier. Anyhow, AFAIK there is no way to do that without killing garbage-collector performance in the process, which in my book means "not doable".

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I've updated the question. The addition of this aspect is is only temporary, to help verify thread safety across the entire project. I'll remove it once I'm done.

Comment: @Gravitas: It seems that .NET 4 has exactly what the doctor prescribed -- see the updated answer.

Comment: +1 for the revised answer, exactly what I was thinking. A small nitpick though: `CWT<K,V>` has the (unnecessary, imo) restriction that the values -- and not just the keys -- must be ref-types, so you couldn't directly use a `long` or a `Guid`. (No reason why you can't use `CWT<K,object>` though and just box the value. Or write your own custom wrapper class.)

Comment: @LukeH: Good catch, I just updated the answer to explicitly mentioned that. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

An active (not automatic) solution while debugging is to right click on an instance and chose "Make Object ID". It'll append a `{$1}` next to your instance name and class.

If later on, you stumble upon another instance, it will be missing that `{$1}` mark.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot inherit all your classes from a base class or interface and require implementation of a UniqueID property?

Another possibility is to wrap them in a class containing a generic object reference and the unique ID, then cataloging them as they are asked for in a lazy way.  Cleaning up such a catalog of unique assignments could be awkward.

Answer (score 0):

Could potentially use:

```
ClassName + MethodName + this.GetHashCode();
```

Although GetHashCode() does not guarantee a unique value, if its paired with the class name and method name, the likelihood of a clash reduces.

Even if there is a clash, the only effect will be that it generates more warnings in the logs, which isn't a big deal.

Comment: Decided against the method, as GetHashCode() is not guaranteed to be unique, whereas ObjectIDGenerator is.