# How to call a second-level base class method like base.base.GetHashCode()

Tags: c#, inheritance

```
class A
{
    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return 1;
    }
}
class B : A
{
    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return ((object)this).GetHashCode();
    }
}

new B().GetHashCode()
```

this overflows the stack. How can I  call `Object.GetHashCode()` from `B.GetHashCode()`?

edit: `B` now inherits from `A`.

Comment: Did you mean to have class B inherit from class A?

Comment: @AakashM - good spot! I mentally inserted it without noticing it isn't there; I think we can assume it should be...

Comment: This is not legal in C#. Is it possible to redesign your class hierarchy so that derived types do not need to know about the implementation details of all of their base types?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

(edit - misread question)

If you want to get the original `object.GetHashCode()` version; you can't - at least, not unless `A` makes it available via something like:

```
protected int GetBaseHashCode() { return base.GetHashCode();}
```

(and have `B` call `GetBaseHashCode()`).

The reason it overflows is that `GetHashCode` is (obviously) virtual - it doesn't matter if you cast it to `object`; it still starts at the most-derived implementation in the actual object, i.e. `B.GetHashCode()` (hence the explosion).

Comment: Actually, I thought you can use reflection to call a specific version of a method, even if it is virtual.

Comment: @LBushkin - I thought that too; but when I tried it a little while ago (using custom IL and "call" instead of "callvirt") the CLI rejected it, saying it could destabilise the runtime (and that was for a trivial example).

Comment: You could blatantly cheat by creating a `DynamicMethod`.  Something like Dogett's [answer to a similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4357729/use-reflection-to-invoke-a-overrided-base-method/4358250#4358250)

Comment: [Try this answer to a similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14415506/177710): quick, easy, and you don't need to touch the intermediate class!

Answer (score 14):

You can use `RuntimeHelpers.GetHashCode(object)` to get the original hash code of the object:

```
  class A
  {
    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
      Console.WriteLine("base hashcode is: " + base.GetHashCode());

      return 1;
    }
  }

  class Program
  {
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      A a = new A();

      Console.WriteLine("A's hashcode: " + a.GetHashCode());

      Console.WriteLine("A's original hashcode: " + RuntimeHelpers.GetHashCode(a));
    }
  }
```

This produces the following result:

> base hashcode is: 54267293
>    A's hashcode: 1
>    A's original hashcode: 54267293

If you take a look at `RuntimeHelpers.GetHashCode(object)` in Reflector, you'll see that it calls the internal static method `object.InternalGetHashCode(object)`. If you'd like to know more, have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/720177/default-implementation-for-object-gethashcode) regarding the default implementation of GetHashCode.

Answer (score 7):

I'm using an external library and I wanted to call the base.base also (because of a bug in certain case). After some research I came across this page http://www.rsdn.ru/forum/dotnet/475911.aspx

It's quite simple: You define a delegate using the base class you want to call your method and set the object pointer to *this (or the object you want)

So, the important code is:

```
public delegate void MD();

public void Test() {
        // A is the base class you want to call the method.
        A a = new A();
        // Create your delegate using the method name "M" with the instance 'a' of the base class
        MD am = (MD)Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(MD), a, "M");
        // Get the target of the delegate and set it to your object (this in most case)
        am.GetType().BaseType.BaseType.GetField("_target", BindingFlags.Instance BindingFlags.NonPublic).SetValue(am, this);
        // call the method using the delegate.
        am();
    }
```

Comment: "quite simple" is not what I thought when I read the code but it works like a charm :-) !

Answer (score 0):

If you can modify the code of the sub-sub class then you can implement the functionality of the sub-sub-method with a static method. This static (public) method has as first parameter an object of the class. That way you can call it from everywhere.

```
class A
{
    public static int CalcHashCode(A obj)
    {
        return 1;
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return CalcHashCode(this);
    }
}
class B : A
{
    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return A.CalcHashCode(this);
    }
}
```