# disable the default Enter/Return key behavior in a datagridview

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, datagridview

In vb.net datagridview the default Enter/Return key behavior is to move to the next row is there a quick and easy way to avoid that.

Any suggestions are welcome

Comment: I wrote an answer to this question here. https://stackoverflow.com/a/76125199/8458887

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You can try something like this in the gridview key down event

```
Private Sub DataGridView1_Keydown (...) Handles DataGridView1.KeyDown
   If e.KeyCode = Keys.Enter Then
       ' Your code here
       e.SuppressKeyPress = True
  End If 
End Sub
```

Another option would be to create a custom grid view control

[DataGridView.ProcessDataGridViewKey Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.processdatagridviewkey.aspx)

Comment: Application terminates as soon as it comes to e.suppressKeyPress = true .

Answer (score 4):

You can just use keyPress event:

```
 private void dataGridView1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
            {
                //You're Code
            }
            e.Handled = true;
            return;
        }
```

Comment: This worked like a charm. Simple but only solution of the proposed, which worked for me.

Comment: KeyDown, not KeyPress. Scanning the code missed that. My tip off was there's no e.KeyCode in KeyPress.

Answer (score 3):

I myself, when disabling the Enter key’s default behavior on a `DataGridView`, want to be able to achieve a similar effect to setting [`DataGridView.StandardTab`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.standardtab) to `true`. Enabling `StandardTab` enables the user to more easily navigate between different controls in a form. This makes it behave more like a `ListBox`, especially if the `DataGridView` only has one column. The default behavior of of the Enter key and the behavior which I would expect from setting a (nonexistent) `DataGridView.StandardEnter` key to `true` would be to send the key event to containing controls, probably resulting in the [`Form.AcceptButton`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.acceptbutton) being activated. The proposed methods of [setting `KeyEventArgs.SuppressKeyPress = true` in `DataGridView.KeyDown`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1887346/429091) or [not even firing `DataGridView.KeyDown` when the input key is Enter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1887553/429091) do not enable “standard” Enter key behavior; these methods instead let the Enter key event get swallowed.

The following shows how I have managed to get “Standard” Enter key behavior (including invoking `AcceptButton` appropriately) out of a DataGridView. It is ugly because I do not know a better way to run the logic in `Control.ProcessDialogKey()` (which is just to call the Parent (the container)’s `ProcessDialogKey()` or return `false` if there is no Parent) than to copy it into my own derived class. (I essentially need to use the [invalid/impossible `base.base.ProcessDialogKey()` syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1006530/429091) to work around `System.Windows.Forms`’s non-extensibility in a cleaner manner). Because of this, I am forced to use reflection to access the protected `Control.ProcessDialogKey()` method of the parent (the container) `Control` object when it exists.

`DataGridVew.IsInputKey()` returns `true` for `Keys.Enter`. This enables it to see the Enter key in its `DataGridView.OnKeyDown()` method where it eventually calls [`DataGridView.ProcessEnterKey()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.processenterkey) which reacts to the Enter key in different ways based on the setting of [`DataGridView.EditMode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.editmode). But this also disables sending the key event to `ProcessDialogKey()` from where normal controls would bubble the Enter key event to their Parents (enabling `AcceptButton` to work, for example). Thus, we revert this behavior by overriding `IsInputKey()` and now `DataGridView.ProcessDialogKey()` will get called when Enter is pressed.

But that is not enough. `DataGridView.ProcessDialogKey()` has a hardcoded call to `DataGridView.ProcessEnterKey()` and only calls its base `Control.ProcessDialogKey()` if `ProcessEnterKey()` returns false. At this point, it would seem common sense to override `ProcessEnterKey()` with something that would just return `false` when we want standard Enter key behavior. But, alas, it is a non-virtual method. Thus, we are forced to override something we can override, `DataGridView.ProcessDialogKey()`, and reimplement it while skipping the call to `ProcessEnterKey()`. This is where we are also unable to directly call `Control.ProcessDialogKey()` and are forced to use reflection to call the parent/container object’s `ProcessDialogKey()` method. But once we successfully make that call, we finally have standard Enter behavior and `AcceptButton` is accessible even while the `DataGridView` has focus!

```cs
/// <summary>
///   A DataGridView with a StandardEnter property which behaves
///   like StandardTab.
/// </summary>
class StandardEnterDataGridView
: DataGridView
{
    /// <summary>
    ///   Like StandardTab but for the Enter key.
    /// </summary>
    [Category("Behavior"), Description("Disable default edit/advance to next row behavior of of the Enter key.")]
    public bool StandardEnter { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    ///   Implement StandardEnter.
    /// </summary>
    protected override bool IsInputKey(Keys keyData)
    {
        if (StandardEnter && keyData == Keys.Enter)
            // Force this key to be treated like something to pass
            // to ProcessDialogKey() (like the Enter key normally
            // would be for controls which aren’t DataGridView).
            return false;

        return base.IsInputKey(keyData);
    }

    private static MethodInfo _Control_ProcessDialogKey = typeof(Control).GetMethod("ProcessDialogKey", BindingFlags.Instance|BindingFlags.NonPublic);

    protected override bool ProcessDialogKey(Keys keyData)
    {
        if (StandardEnter && keyData == Keys.Enter)
            // Copy the default implementation of
            // Control.ProcessDialogKey(). Since we can’t access
            // the base class (DataGridView)’s base class’s
            // implementation directly, and since we cannot
            // legally access Control.ProcessDialogKey() on other
            // Control object, we are forced to use reflection.
            return Parent == null ? false : (bool)_Control_ProcessDialogKey.Invoke(Parent, new object[] {keyData, });

        return base.ProcessDialogKey(keyData);
    }
}
```

Comment: I just change the declaration of my Gride to this new class but nothing happens, ENTER KEY still going to the next row :-/ 
            this.dbGride = new StandardEnterDataGridView();

Comment: @duardbr I haven’t looked at this code in a long time, but given that you wrote `this.dbGride = new StandardEnterDataGridView();` in your comment, did you remember to set the `StandardEnter` property to `true`? Perhaps `this.dbGride = new StandardEnterDataGridView { StandardEnter = true, };`. Or if you’re using VS Designer try enabling the `StandardEnter` property in the Designer’s property grid view.

Comment: Thanks for reply, yes, StandardEnter is True and nothing happens

Answer (score 2):

Override the DataGridView (write your own that inherits from it), and process the *OnKeyDown* method.

```
public partial class UserControl1 : DataGridView
{
    public UserControl1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override void OnKeyDown(KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
            return;

        base.OnKeyDown(e);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I am adding this foot note to this as I was very interested in this article since it ran close to a different problem I had with the DataGridView.  This is that the fact the Enter key takes you to the cell below, preventing a users ability to do simple editing to text in a cell.  Having overridden the class and spent much time on this, I finally found the following article:
[Use Enter to add new line in datagridview cell](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/846facec-c43a-435b-9b63-4ed2e8d4f8f7/use-enter-to-add-new-line-in-datagridview-cell)

If this is your only issue, then to know SHIFT+ENTER works (however unintuitive), might save you a lot of time!  Think I will just add a label to the form to remind users.

Answer (score 0):

The accepted solution did not work for me.  The code below DID.  From http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?603242-Block-enter-key-in-datagridview-in-vb-net: (original source unknown)

```
Public Class clsDataGridView
Inherits System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView

Protected Overrides Function ProcessCmdKey(ByRef msg As System.Windows.Forms.Message, ByVal keyData As System.Windows.Forms.Keys) As Boolean

    If keyData = Keys.Return Or keyData = Keys.Tab Then
        If CurrentCellAddress.X = ColumnCount - 1 Then
            keyData = Keys.Cancel
            With msg
                .WParam = CType(Keys.Cancel, IntPtr)
            End With
        Else
            keyData = Keys.Tab
            With msg
                .WParam = CType(Keys.Tab, IntPtr)
            End With
        End If
    End If

    If keyData = (Keys.Shift Or Keys.Tab) Then
        If CurrentCellAddress.X = 0 Then
            keyData = Keys.Cancel
            With msg
                .WParam = CType(Keys.Cancel, IntPtr)
            End With
        End If
    End If
    Return MyBase.ProcessCmdKey(msg, keyData)

End Function

Protected Overrides Function ProcessDialogKey(ByVal keyData As System.Windows.Forms.Keys) As Boolean

    If keyData = Keys.Return Or keyData = Keys.Tab Then
        If CurrentCellAddress.X = ColumnCount - 1 Then
            keyData = Keys.Cancel
        Else
            keyData = Keys.Tab
        End If
    End If

    If keyData = (Keys.Shift Or Keys.Tab) Then
        If CurrentCellAddress.X = 0 Then
            keyData = Keys.Cancel
        End If
    End If
    Return MyBase.ProcessDialogKey(keyData)

End Function

End Class
```