# How to prevent going to next row after editing a DataGridViewTextBoxColumn and pressing EnterKey?

Tags: c#, datagridview, focus, keypress, datagridviewtextboxcell

I'm working on a program with `DataGridViews`. 
In one `DatagridView` there is a `DataGridViewTextBoxColumn`, which is enabled to be edited by the user. When the user is done with typing the numbers into it, he presses ENTER on the keyboard. Now the `DataGridView` does all its `Events`, and after all `Events`, the last thing is the problem.

Everything is done, and Windows is going to Select the next `DataGridViewRow`, and I'm not able to prevent this.

I tried

```
if (e.KeyData == Keys.Enter) e.SuppressKeyPress = true; // or e.Handled
```

in nearly every event I found. Sadly I was only able to Prevent the ENTER key when the `DataGridViewTextBoxColumn` is not in edit mode.

Heres my methode t find the ENTER while in Editing

Adding the Event

```
private void dgr_EditingControlShowing(object sender, DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs e)
{
    e.Control.KeyPress += new KeyPressEventHandler(dgr_KeyPress_NumericTester);
}
```

And this is the event to accept numeric input only.

```
private void dgr_KeyPress_NumericTester(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    if (!Char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar) && e.KeyChar != 8) e.Handled = true;
}
```

To explain in detail:

When the user enters a Value, that has some dependings, I would like to give another control the focus, so he is used to correct the dependings.

I also tried it with `DependingControl.Focus()` but the last "enter" is going to be the last thing on the view.

Does someone know how to prevent this?

Comment: You need only to override the `ProcessCmdKey`, see [here for how](http://windowsclient.net/blogs/faqs/archive/2006/05/30/how-do-i-make-the-enter-key-behave-like-the-tab-key-in-a-datagrid-moving-to-the-next-cell.aspx ) and [here for why][2] [2]: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jfoscoding/archive/2005/01/24/359334.aspx

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well, I managed to get something working that does what you want (or at least does the hard part, I think you have already done most of the other stuff) but the solution makes my skin crawl.

What I ended up with to "cancel" the enter key event when editing a cell as to use a mixture of the `CellEndEdit` event and the `SelectionChanged` event.

I introduced a couple of class level fields that store some state - in particular what row we are in at the end of editing a cell and whether we are stopping a selection changed.

The code looks like this:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private int currentRow;
    private bool resetRow = false;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        // deleted out all the binding code of the grid to focus on the interesting stuff

        dataGridView1.CellEndEdit += new DataGridViewCellEventHandler(dataGridView1_CellEndEdit);

        // Use the DataBindingComplete event to attack the SelectionChanged, 
        // avoiding infinite loops and other nastiness.
        dataGridView1.DataBindingComplete += new DataGridViewBindingCompleteEventHandler(dataGridView1_DataBindingComplete);
    }

    void dataGridView1_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (resetRow)
        {
            resetRow = false;
            dataGridView1.CurrentCell = dataGridView1.Rows[currentRow].Cells[0];          
        }
    }

    void dataGridView1_CellEndEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        resetRow = true;
        currentRow = e.RowIndex;
    }

    void dataGridView1_DataBindingComplete(object sender, DataGridViewBindingCompleteEventArgs e)
    {
        dataGridView1.SelectionChanged += new EventHandler(dataGridView1_SelectionChanged);
    }
}
```

You'll want to test this thoroughly to make sure it does exactly what you need. I only checked to see that it does stop a row change when pressing enter out of an editing control.

As I said - I'm not too happy with needing to do something like this - it feels quite brittle, and also like it could have weird side effects. But if you must have this behaviour, and you test it well I think this is the only way to do what you want.

Comment: This is working fine for me. Just one small bug when I'm trying to leave a `DataGridViewCheckBoxCell` i must not set resetRow, becourse it will jail my focus in the CheckBox. `if (dataGridView1.CurrentCell is DataGridViewCheckBoxCell) resetRow = false;` I was working with SelectedRow instead of changing the CurrentCell property, and this was not working well in my test... now its fine, thx a lot for this!

Answer (score 11):

I tried this for changing the Enter behaviour for your Grid by inheriting a customcolumn from 
Textbox column and overriding the below event

```
protected override bool ProcessDialogKey(Keys keyData)
{
    if (keyData == Keys.Enter)
       return base.ProcessDialogKey(Keys.Tab);
    else
       return base.ProcessDialogKey(keyData);
}
```

So instead of the Enter Key being sent it emulates the action for Tab which will move to the next cell. Hope this helps

Comment: Also a great way. Thanks for this too!

Answer (score 6):

```
Private Sub DataGridView1_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.KeyDown
    If e.KeyData = Keys.Enter Then e.Handled = True
End Sub
```

It's just a workaround, not a real solution, but it works.

Answer (score 2):

**You can do it simply....**

1...Create the KeyDown Event for that grid view.(Go to properties on the gridview and double click the KeyDown event).

2...Past this code -

```
if(e.KeyData == Keys.Enter)
{
  e.Handled = true;
}
```

3...Finally its look like this.

```
private void dgvSearchResults_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
  if (e.KeyData == Keys.Enter)
   {
    e.Handled = true;
   }
}
```

4..Run the program and see.

Answer (score 2):

This answer really comes late...

But i had the exact same Problem and did not want to cache rows etc.
So i googled around and this is my solution to the question. Credits to [How to prevent an Enter key press from ending EditMode in a DataGridView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19631965/how-to-prevent-an-enter-key-press-from-ending-editmode-in-a-datagridview)

Inherit from DataGridView and add this code (vb.net):

```
Protected Overrides Function ProcessCmdKey(ByRef msg As Message, keyData As Keys) As Boolean
    If Commons.Options.RowWiseNavigation AndAlso Me.IsCurrentCellInEditMode AndAlso (keyData = Keys.Enter Or keyData = Keys.Tab) Then
        ' End EditMode, then raise event, so the standard-handler can run and the refocus is being done
        Me.EndEdit()
        OnKeyDown(New KeyEventArgs(keyData))
        Return True
    End If

    'Default
    Return MyBase.ProcessCmdKey(msg, keyData)
End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

I know that this question was asked since long time ago but the answer may be useful for those who search in future i hope so. the best solution is to use your custom column and for textbox its easy because we will take advantage of the built in classes

```
class Native
{
    public const uint WM_KEYDOWN = 0x100;
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern bool PostMessage(IntPtr hWnd, UInt32 Msg, Int32 wParam, Int32 lParam);
}
//the column that will be added to dgv
public class CustomTextBoxColumn : DataGridViewColumn
{
    public CustomTextBoxColumn() : base(new CustomTextCell()) { }
    public override DataGridViewCell CellTemplate
    {
        get { return base.CellTemplate; }
        set
        {
            if (value != null && !value.GetType().IsAssignableFrom(typeof(CustomTextCell)))
            {
                throw new InvalidCastException("Must be a CustomTextCell");
            }
            base.CellTemplate = value;
        }
    }
}
//the cell used in the previous column
public class CustomTextCell : DataGridViewTextBoxCell
{
    public override Type EditType
    {
        get { return typeof(CustomTextBoxEditingControl); }
    }
}
//the edit control that will take data from user
public class CustomTextBoxEditingControl : DataGridViewTextBoxEditingControl
{
    protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
    {
        //we need to handle the keydown event
        if (m.Msg == Native.WM_KEYDOWN)
        {
            if((ModifierKeys&Keys.Shift)==0)//make sure that user isn't entering new line in case of warping is set to true
            {
                Keys key=(Keys)m.WParam;
                if (key == Keys.Enter)
                {
                    if (this.EditingControlDataGridView != null)
                    {
                        if(this.EditingControlDataGridView.IsHandleCreated)
                        {
                            //sent message to parent dvg
                            Native.PostMessage(this.EditingControlDataGridView.Handle, (uint)m.Msg, m.WParam.ToInt32(), m.LParam.ToInt32());
                            m.Result = IntPtr.Zero;
                        }
                        return;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        base.WndProc(ref m);
    }
}
```

then we come to the dgv itself i used a new class derived from DataGridView and added my columns and handled the enter key from the wndproc also

```
void Initialize()
{
    CustomTextBoxColumn colText = new CustomTextBoxColumn();
    colText.DataPropertyName = colText.Name = columnTextName;
    colText.HeaderText = columnTextAlias;
    colText.DefaultCellStyle.WrapMode = DataGridViewTriState.True;
    this.Columns.Add(colText);
    DataGridViewTextBoxColumn colText2 = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
    colText2.DataPropertyName = colText2.Name = columnText2Name;
    colText2.HeaderText = columnText2Alias;
    colText2.DefaultCellStyle.WrapMode = DataGridViewTriState.False;
    this.Columns.Add(colText2);
}
protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
{
    //the enter key is sent by edit control
    if (m.Msg == Native.WM_KEYDOWN)
    {
        if ((ModifierKeys & Keys.Shift) == 0)
        {
            Keys key = (Keys)m.WParam;
            if (key == Keys.Enter)
            {
                MoveToNextCell();
                m.Result = IntPtr.Zero;
                return;
            }
        }
    }

    base.WndProc(ref m);
}

//move the focus to the next cell in same row or to the first cell in next row then begin editing
public void MoveToNextCell()
{
    int CurrentColumn, CurrentRow;
    CurrentColumn = this.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex;
    CurrentRow = this.CurrentCell.RowIndex;
    if (CurrentColumn == this.Columns.Count - 1 && CurrentRow != this.Rows.Count - 1)
    {
        this.CurrentCell = Rows[CurrentRow + 1].Cells[1];//0 index is for No and readonly
        this.BeginEdit(false);
    }
    else if(CurrentRow != this.Rows.Count - 1)
    {
        base.ProcessDataGridViewKey(new KeyEventArgs(Keys.Tab));
        this.BeginEdit(false);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply Do that it will be working all right.

```
private void dataGridViewX1_CellEndEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {

        SendKeys.Send("{UP}");
        SendKeys.Send("{Right}");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36243682/stop-unnecessary-row-creation-in-datagridview), I've created my own. You don't need to catch *KeyDown_Event* on the DataGrid for the *Enter_key*, but rather toggle the **AllowUserToAddRows** property. In my case, I opted for the *CellContentDoubleClick* for enabling it:

```
private void myDataGrid_CellBeginEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellCancelEventArgs e) {
    myDataGrid.AllowUserToAddRows = false;
}

private void myDataGrid_CellContentDoubleClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e) {
    myDataGrid.AllowUserToAddRows = true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The only way i found to do this was creating a custom DataGridView.

Edit:
This change the default behavior of the arrow keys, and permit the use of the arrow keys in editing. You can change this removing "e.KeyCode == Keys.Left || e.KeyCode == Keys.Right".

```
    public class CustomDataGridview : DataGridView
    {
        protected override bool ProcessDataGridViewKey(KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter || e.KeyCode == Keys.Left || e.KeyCode == Keys.Right)
            {
                return false;
                //if (IsCurrentCellInEditMode)   // disable the keys only in EditMode
                //{
                //    return false;
                //}
            }
            return base.ProcessDataGridViewKey(e);
        }

        protected override bool ProcessDialogKey(Keys keyData)
        {
            if (keyData == Keys.Enter)
            {
                EndEdit();
                return true;
            }
            return base.ProcessDialogKey(keyData);
        }
    }

    CustomDataGridview dgvCustom = new CustomDataGridview();
    DataGridViewTextBoxColumn InputFile2 = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
    DataGridViewTextBoxColumn OutputFile2 = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
    DataGridViewComboBoxColumn Format2 = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();
    DataGridViewTextBoxColumn Options2 = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();

    private void SetupDataGridView()
    {
        //All your DataGridView settings
    }

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        SetupDataGridView();
    }
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

If you need to just close the form on enter, you can use following code. I  suppose that the grid is readonly and you don't need to distinquish the situation in which the enter was pressed.

```
public class DataGridViewNoEnter : DataGridView
{       
    protected override bool ProcessDataGridViewKey(KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
        {
            ((Form)this.TopLevelControl).DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
            return false;
        }
        return base.ProcessDataGridViewKey(e);
    }      
}
```