# change the row in one dataGridView when arrow Keys are pressed in other dataGridView

Tags: c#, datagridview

I went into problem:
I have two `DataGridView` on my form MAIN and SUB, now here is what I want to do that if MAIN `DataGridView` cell is in edit mode and user press the down arrow then instead of going down to next row in MAIN `DataGridView` it should step to next row in SUB `DataGridView`

I have created an event on `EditingControlShowing` by handling the `PreviewKeyDown` but it works only if there is one row in MAIN `DataGridView` or i am on the Last row in MAIN dataGridView but if there are more then one row in MAIN `DataGridView` then if i press <kbd>Arrow Up</kbd> or <kbd>Arrow Down</kbd> it moves through MAIN `DataGridView` Rows only.

I have tried to control it at `DataGridView` peviewKey but arrow keys does not register there, also <kbd>Arrow Keys</kbd> does not register at `DataGridView` `KeyDown` and `keypress` while in edit mode

they are registered at keyup of `DataGridView` but at this point it do two thing move the rows down or up in both dataGridViews

what I want that if MAIN `DataGridView` cell is in editmode and up or down arrow key are pressed then it only change the row in SUB `DataGridView` not in main `DataGridView`

Any Ideas!

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried programmatically selecting rows in the sub dataGridView? You can try getting the index of the selected row in the sub grid when the Main PreviewKeyDown event fires and then selecting the next sub dataGridView row like this for example:

```
subDataGridView.Rows(index).Selected = False
subDataGridView.Rows(index + 1).Selected = True
```

or maybe

```
subDataGridView.CurrentCell = DataGridView1.Rows(index + 1).Cells(0);
```

Comment: Yes, i did that, but it only work if cell is in non-edit mode, but if cell is in edit mode then this event won't register arrow keys

Comment: Have you tried the [EditingControlShowing](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.editingcontrolshowing.aspx) event?

More info in this question, looks like something you could use: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8538120/cell-in-editmode-doesnt-fire-onkeydown-event-in-c-sharp

Comment: the matter is resolved by overriding the dataGridView and making a custom column found solution here : 
http://weblogs.asp.net/rweigelt/1647400
Worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

the matter is resolved by overriding the "dataGridView" and making a custom column found solution here : 
[enter link description here](http://weblogs.asp.net/rweigelt/1647400) 
Worked like a charm.