# How to prevent going to next row after editing a DataGridViewComboBoxColumn and pressing EnterKey?

Tags: c#, datagridview, focus, keypress, datagridviewcomboboxcell

I've got a form with a DataGridView.
In the Datagridview I have some DataGridViewComboBoxColumn and some DataGridViewTextBoxColumn.
The problem is that I want to use **Enter** instead of Tab to switch from one cell to another, even when I'm in editmode in the cell.

[screenshot of the datagridview to customize](http://www.bruno.pacifici.name/public/problem/bolle.png)

[screenshot of the combobox to customize](http://www.bruno.pacifici.name/public/problem/ComboBoxInEditMode.PNG)

I succeded in implementing the solution provided in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9917202/249120) https://stackoverflow.com/a/9917202/249120 for the Textbox Columns, but I can't implement it for a Combobox Column. How to do it?

Important:for the Textbox Columns the defaultCellStyle must have the property "wrap" to True. 
It worked (when you press enter it's like you are pressing a tab) so I decided to test it also with a "CustomComboBoxColumn" and I tried to create a code very similar to the one for the CustomTextBoxColumn , but it doesn't work :

```
#region CustomComboBoxColumn

public class CustomComboBoxColumn : DataGridViewColumn
{
    public CustomComboBoxColumn() : base(new CustomComboBoxCell()) { }

    public override DataGridViewCell CellTemplate
    {
        get { return base.CellTemplate; }
        set
        {
            if (value != null && !value.GetType().IsAssignableFrom(typeof(CustomComboBoxCell)))
            {
                throw new InvalidCastException("Must be a CustomComboBoxCell");
            }
            base.CellTemplate = value;
        }
    }
}

public class CustomComboBoxCell : DataGridViewComboBoxCell
{

    public override Type EditType
    {
        get { return typeof(CustomComboBoxEditingControl); }
    }
}

public class CustomComboBoxEditingControl : DataGridViewComboBoxEditingControl
{
    protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
    {
        //we need to handle the keydown event
        if (m.Msg == Native.WM_KEYDOWN)
        {
            if ((ModifierKeys & Keys.Shift) == 0)//make sure that user isn't entering new line in case of warping is set to true
            {
                Keys key = (Keys)m.WParam;
                if (key == Keys.Enter)
                {
                    if (this.EditingControlDataGridView != null)
                    {
                        if (this.EditingControlDataGridView.IsHandleCreated)
                        {
                            //sent message to parent dvg
                            Native.PostMessage(this.EditingControlDataGridView.Handle, (uint)m.Msg, m.WParam.ToInt32(), m.LParam.ToInt32());
                            m.Result = IntPtr.Zero;
                        }
                        return;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        base.WndProc(ref m);
    }
}

#endregion
```

The final result of this is a ComboBoxColumn without the properties DataSource, DisplayMember, Items, ValueMember, but when pressing the Enter goes to the next cell.
What else to do?

Comment: Can you add some information about what you have tried?

Comment: i'm not sure what the problem is?? i think when you select an item of combobox it move to next cell, if so? does this happen when using mouse also or when pressing enter key only?? i advise you to check the selection change event.

Comment: the comboboxcolumn has displaystyle: nothing and flatstyle: flat .if I select an item and I press enter it works, if I select an item using mouse it goes to the next row, if I write the value manually (It's what I want to do really) and I press ENTER it goes to the next row.

Answer (score 1):

an answer and a comment to Bruno Pacifici answer:

**OR** you can override only 1 method "ProcessCmdKey" which will do the same:

```
    protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData)
    {
        //Override behavior on Enter press
        if (keyData == Keys.Enter)
        {
            if (CurrentCell != null)
            {
                if (CurrentCell.IsInEditMode)
                {
                    //Do Stuff if cell is currently being edited
                    return ProcessTabKey(keyData);
                }
                else
                {
                    //Do Stuff if cell is NOT yet currently edited
                    BeginEdit(true);
                }
            }
        }
        //Process all other keys as expected
        return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);
    }
```

P.S. Why posting only link as an answer, if the answer is not too large?
I have experienced so many cases, when such "helpful" link did not work anymore.
So, copying some code with link to original source would be more "404"-safe answer.

Answer (score 0):

The solution to my question is incredibly simple.You have to create a custom dataGridView overriding just 2 methods. See here : http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winformsdatacontrols/thread/a44622c0-74e1-463b-97b9-27b87513747e#faq9 .