# Keypress event in cell of datagridview with key return

Tags: c#, datagridview

Code run when I use with key A.
But code not run when I use with key return.

```
    void dataGridView1_EditingControlShowing(object sender, DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs e)
    {
        TextBox txt = e.Control as TextBox;
        txt.KeyPress += new KeyPressEventHandler(txt_KeyPress);
    }

    void txt_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        /* Code run. */
        if(e.KeyChar == (char)Keys.A)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Hello");
        }

        /* Code not run! */
        if (e.KeyChar == (char)Keys.Return)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Hello");
        }
    }
```

But it run if I try with a text box.

Comment: It might involve something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5771594/how-to-prevent-going-to-next-row-after-editing-a-datagridviewtextboxcolumn-and-p)..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you TaW!
I solved it like this...

```
void TextBox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e) 
{ 
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter) 
    { 
        e.Handled = true; 
    } 
}

void TextBox1_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, PreviewKeyDownEventArgs e) 
{ 
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Return)
    {
        /* Your code here! */ 
    }
}
```