# How to show listbox on Spacekey press event in DatagridView?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

In my Winform application there is a DataGrid view(***dataGridView1***) and 2 list boxes , ***listBox1*** and ***listBox2*** . In dataGridView1 , there is three columns, Column1 (id) , Column2 (Category) and  Column3 (Items) . I want to display listBox1 , containing Categries when user pressing space bar  and should focus on Items column after pressing enter button.

I found some solutions,  but not working up to my requirements. I want something like,

```
 If (spacebar is pressed &&  dataGridView1.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex== 2)
            {

                listbox1.Visible = true;
                listbox1.Focus();
                listbox1.SelectedIndex = 0;


            }
```

I can't show you my form image because of low reputation.

Thanks to you all !

Comment: Where is user focusing when they press Spacebar, on dataGridView1 column 2 or anywhere on form ? Ps: you can upload your image somewhere else and give link here.

Comment: Nam - exactly , On column 2  , here is my [image](http://1drv.ms/1OiWECQ).

Comment: When user is in id column and if presses enter button , focus should goto second column, listbox should show only user presses spacebar.

Comment: I've posted my solution but I suggest told your user using Tab key instead of Enter key in your ID column is easier than all.

Answer (score 0):

It's a long time since I've used a datagridview, but if you check its events I think you have a CellEnter and a CellLeave event that you can use to check which column is selected and modify the visible property of your list views.

The event handler of CellEnter has a column index parameter to help you.

Answer (score 0):

at datagridview's keydown event

```
 if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Space)//check if space is pressed
    {
      if(dataGridView1.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex== 2)
        {
            listbox1.Visible = true;
            listbox1.Focus();               
        }

    }
```

For checking enter key use this at keydown event of datagrid

```
 if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter) //if enter key is pressed change selected index
  { 
   listbox1.SelectedIndex = 3;
  }
```

Comment: Keycode is not available in Keypress event. I think its only in Keydown? Correct me if i'm wrong.

Comment: you, if you want to do that you need to register the event and then you can do this in  the event code  if (e.KeyChar == (char)32)
       {
         //your code
       }
changed answer for keydown event.

Comment: Nothing happening. here is my code on keypress event on datagrid view, if (e.KeyChar == (char)32)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("You preessed spacebar.");
             

            }

Comment: "you need to register the event",If you dont want to do that you can use key down event for both the conditions.

Answer (score 0):

In column 0 (id), not editing, press enter and move next cell:

```
    private void dataGridView1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyData == Keys.Enter && dataGridView1.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex == 0)
        {
            dataGridView1.CurrentCell = dataGridView1[1, dataGridView1.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex];
        }
    }
```

In column 0 (id), editing, press enter and move next cell (answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5773689/3413552)):

```
    private int currentRow;
    private bool resetRow = false;

    void dataGridView1_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (resetRow)
        {
            resetRow = false;
            dataGridView1.CurrentCell = dataGridView1.Rows[currentRow].Cells[1];
        }
    }

    void dataGridView1_CellEndEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        resetRow = true;
        currentRow = e.RowIndex;
    }
```

*Notes: you may need to bind `SelectionChanged` event after completed binding data to your datagridview instead of binding in design time.

In column 1 (cats) and 2 (items), press spacebar to show list cats and list items:

```
    private void dataGridView1_EditingControlShowing(object sender, DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs e)
    {
        if (dataGridView1.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex == 1)
            ((TextBox)e.Control).KeyPress += new KeyPressEventHandler(col1_KeyPress);
        if (dataGridView1.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex == 2)
            ((TextBox)e.Control).KeyPress += new KeyPressEventHandler(col2_KeyPress);
    }

    void col1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyChar == 32)
        {
            listBox1.Visible = true;
            listBox1.Focus();
            listBox1.SelectedIndex = 0;
        }
    }

    void col2_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyChar == 32)
        {
            listBox2.Visible = true;
            listBox2.Focus();
            listBox2.SelectedIndex = 0;
        }
    }
```