# How do I allow users to insert newlines in a Winforms DataGrid cell?

Tags: winforms, datagridview

In my Winforms application I have a standard datagrid view.  However, in my application I am getting requests to allow users to insert newlines in a cell.  In excel users can do this with alt+enter (or shift+enter, forgot which).  However, I am unsure of how to do this in a Winforms datagrid.

The issue is that by default, if you are editing a cell in a datagrid pressing enter will commit the edit.  I tried adding a check in my Datagrid's KeyDown event for Alt+Enter and had it add a newline but that didn't work.  That also won't allow users to add a newline in the middle of text (since I can't see how I can get the cursor's position while editing a cell).

Does anyone have any idea how I can accomplish this?

Comment: does this help:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1887299/disable-the-default-enter-return-key-behavior-in-a-datagridview

Comment: Oh good link let me give that a try

Comment: Nope that doesn't work, because the DataGrid's KeyDown event doesn't get triggered when editing a cell

Comment: How about this one? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2030542/datagridview-how-can-i-make-the-enter-key-add-a-new-line-instead-of-changing-th

Comment: That mostly does it, but I need to figure out if that solution is worth losing enter to commit (from a usability perspective).  Wish I could have it both ways