# Prevent focus change to next row in Datagridview with checkbox

Tags: vb.net, winforms, datagridview

I have created a datagridview and added a checkbox in 1st column.

```
Fullrowselected = true
```

Now on Enter key press, the row focus changes to next row.
Is there some property setting to change?
How can I prevent this change in row focus?

Comment: Are you saying that you just want to prevent the `Enter` key causing the caret to move to the next row or that you want to prevent it regardless of the way it's done?

Comment: [disable the default Enter/Return key behavior in a datagridview](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1887299/3110834)

Comment: The default behavior is using Enter key to move between rows and Space key for checking or unchecking CheckBox, although you can customize the behavior.

Comment: @RezaAghaei Oh!, Thank You, its done..!

`e.SuppressKeyPress = True` worked for me.

I tried to search but the search keyword didn't match.