# vb.net DataGridView how to stay in current cell when I press enter or tab key?

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

Now I'm making code that after I change a text in a cell and then, when I press enter key or tab key, then the currente cell stay in the same cell which I modified. I searched in here about that ([Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1887299/disable-the-default-enter-return-key-behavior-in-a-datagridview/42656117#42656117))
But it dosen' work for me. What did I make a mistake in that?

```
Public row1, col1 As Integer
Public selectedPart1 As String
Private Sub DataGridView1_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.KeyDown

    row1 = DataGridView1.CurrentCell.RowIndex
    col1 = DataGridView1.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex    
    
    selectedPart1 = DataGridView1(0, row1).Value.ToString

    If e.KeyCode = Keys.Enter Or e.KeyCode = Keys.Tab Then
        MsgBox("ok")
        DataGridView1.CurrentCell = DataGridView1(col1, row1)
        e.SuppressKeyPress = True
    End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

to disable Tab Key you can set `StandardTab` property to True:

```
DataGridView1.StandardTab = True
```

to disable Enter key after edit use events `CellEndEdit` and `SelectionChanged`

```
Private currentRow, currentCell As Integer
Private resetRow As Boolean = False

Private Sub DataGridView1_SelectionChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.SelectionChanged
    If resetRow Then
        resetRow = False
        DataGridView1.CurrentCell = DataGridView1.Rows(currentRow).Cells(currentCell)
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub DataGridView1_CellEndEdit(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellEndEdit
    resetRow = True
    currentRow = e.RowIndex
    currentCell = e.ColumnIndex
End Sub
```