# Global styles in WPF

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, styles

I'm learning how to use styles in WPF and according to information I found on the net, if I define style this way (with target type):

```xml
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">

    <Style  TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Black"/>
    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

...this style will be applied for all buttons in my application. However it seems that my buttons remain the same.
In main window I added resource dictionary to resources collection and I inserted a couple of buttons, however my buttons look the same all the time. Here is the code for main window:

```xml
<Window x:Class="MCTSTrainingChapter1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="GridResources.xaml"/>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="ButtonResources.xaml"/>
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Window.Resources>

    <DockPanel >
        <ToolBar DockPanel.Dock="Top" Height="26" Name="toolBar1"  >
            <Button x:Name="btnBold"  Click="Button_Click">Bold</Button>
            <Button Click="Button_Click_1">Italic</Button>
            <Slider Name="slider1" Minimum="2" Maximum="72" Width="100" ValueChanged="slider1_ValueChanged"></Slider>
        </ToolBar>
        <Grid Name="grid1" Background="{StaticResource GridBackgroundBrush}">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="5"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ListBox Grid.Column="0" Name="listBox1" SelectionChanged="listBox1_SelectionChanged" />
            <GridSplitter Grid.Column="1" Margin="0" Width="5" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
            <RichTextBox Grid.Column="2" Name="richTextBox1"/>
        </Grid>

    </DockPanel>
</Window>
```

Why isn't the Button style applied?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/2406079/238688

Answer (score 6):

As per the answer to this question: [Setting toolbar button sizes using a Style](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2406079/238688)

The ToolBar is applying its own style to the button. This style can be accessed by the resource key `ToolBar.ButtonStyleKey`. Set up your Style with that key, rather than just Targeting the `Button` type, and you'll be set:

```xml
<Style x:Key="{x:Static ToolBar.ButtonStyleKey}" TargetType="Button">
    <Setter Property="Width" Value="100" />
</Style>
```

Answer (score 4):

There is already an answer involving a global style, if you want to explicitly define your style for each button (perhaps in the future of your project) you would want to name the style:

```
<Style x:Key="buttonStyleOne" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Black"/>
</Style>
```

and then apply it to a button you want to use the style via:

```
<Button Style="{DynamicResource buttonStyleOne}">Content!</Button>
```

Comment: +1 It's worth noting that this works on Buttons placed inside ToolBars, as well.