# How to make toolbar buttons share same width?

Tags: c#, wpf, toolbar

I have a toolbar

[image: Toolbar add/edit/remove]

Code:

```
<ToolBarTray>
    <ToolBar>
        <Button>
            <StackPanel>
                <Image/>
                <Label/>
            </StackPanel>
        </Button>
        <Button>
            <StackPanel>
                <Image/>
                <Label/>
            </StackPanel>
        </Button>
        <Button>
            <StackPanel>
                <Image/>
                <Label/>
            </StackPanel>
        </Button>
    </ToolBar>
</ToolBarTray>
```

On Image I only set the `Source` and on the Label I only set the `Content`.

However as the image shows, the buttons aren't sharing the same width. "Remove" button is wider than the others.

How can I make it so that all toolbar buttons will share the same width as the "Remove" button?

Comment: You can manually set the `Width` property, or `MinWidth` property if you prefer.  By default, they are set to auto size to the content, which is why your Remote button is larger than the other two.

Comment: I added the `Stretch` property to my answer below, it is possible to set that the same way as the `Width` as shown in the answer. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way you could set the `Width` of all of your buttons at the same time, is to use a `Setter` in your `ToolBar.Resources`, like so:

```
<ToolBar>
  <ToolBar.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="{x:Static ToolBar.ButtonStyleKey}" TargetType="Button">
      <Setter Property="Width" Value="80"/>
    </Style>
  </ToolBar.Resources>
  <Button>
  ...
  <Button>
  ...
</ToolBar>
```

That way you don't need to manually set the width on each `Button` individually.

You could also use a `Setter` to set the `Stretch` property, like so:

```
      <Setter Property="Stretch" Value="None"/>
```

**Edit:**

Apparently, according to https://stackoverflow.com/a/2406213/3101082, you need to ensure that you are setting the `Style` using the `x:Key="{x:Static ToolBar.ButtonStyleKey}"` in order for it to apply to `ToolBar` buttons.  I have updated my answer to reflect this.

Comment: That's a much better suggestion than my own. Good catch.

Comment: Also, the `Width` may vary.  I just used 80 as an example, but depending on the content of the buttons, you may need to use a larger value.

Answer (score 1):

This will likely work, I haven't tested it but by specifying the width of the button and the image scaling, you should find it does the trick.

```
<Button Width="intValue">
   <StackPanel>
       <Image Source="yourImage" 
              RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode="Fant" />
       <Label/>
   </StackPanel>
</Button>
```

Comment: Almost, just instead of using RenderOptions you actually have to set `Stretch` to `None` :)