# C#: Any way to skip over one of the base calls in polymorphism?

Tags: c#, inheritance, polymorphism, overriding, virtual-functions

```
class GrandParent
{
    public virtual void Foo() { ... }
}

class Parent : GrandParent
{
    public override void Foo()
    {
       base.Foo();

       //Do additional work
    }
}

class Child : Parent
{
    public override void Foo()
    {
        //How to skip Parent.Foo and just get to the GrandParent.Foo base?

        //Do additional work
    }
}
```

---

As the code above shows, how can I have the Child.Foo() make a call into GrandParent.Foo() instead of going into Parent.Foo()? `base.Foo()` takes me to the Parent class first.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that the .net runtime supports this. Related reading http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2010/03/29/putting-a-base-in-the-middle.aspx

Comment: Perhaps if you state *why* you want to do this, we could help you rework your architecture?

Comment: @CodeInChaos: even if it is supported, it will cause ChaosInCode.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your design is wrong if you need this.
Instead, put the per-class logic in `DoFoo` and don't call `base.DoFoo` when you don't need to.

```
class GrandParent
{
    public void Foo()
    {
        // base logic that should always run here:
        // ...

        this.DoFoo(); // call derived logic
    }

    protected virtual void DoFoo() { }
}

class Parent : GrandParent
{
    protected override void DoFoo()
    {    
       // Do additional work (no need to call base.DoFoo)
    }
}

class Child : Parent
{
    protected override void DoFoo()
    {  
        // Do additional work (no need to call base.DoFoo)
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to make `GrandParent` `abstract` for this to work. Compling this tells you that `'GrandParent.DoFoo()' is abstract but it is contained in non-abstract class 'GrandParent'`

Answer (score 6):

I think there is something wrong with your design here.  Essentially, you want to "break" the rules of polymorphism.  You are saying `Child` should derive from `Parent` but want to conveniently skip the implementation in it's parent.

Re-think your design.

Answer (score 3):

No. It wouldn't be reliable anyway. You, as the implementer of your class, get to choose your immediate base class. But who is to say that a later release of `Parent` might not inherit from `ParentBase`, that in turn inherits from `GrandParent`? So long as `Parent` is still implementing the correct contract, this should not cause any issues for those classes inheriting from `Parent`.

Answer (score 2):

No, this isn't possible. Imagine how crazy things would be if this was possible.

If you want something specific skipped in the `Child` case, consider reworking your design to better represent what you need (e.g. maybe you need to override something else in the `Child` class, too). Or, you could provide another `Foo()` in the `Parent` class that doesn't do anything except call its `base.Foo()`.

Answer (score 1):

If you have control of the code, the simplest way is to create a protected method in Parent class that only call base.Foo() and your child class Foo implementation call that method explicitly

Answer (score 0):

We had exactly this scenario on a large project where the derived methods were called from various locations. Due to change management and QA scripts not to be broken, among other constraints, "drastic" refactoring and class re-structuring are not always possible on a large mature project. Also we did not want to override the method and exclude all base functionality. Most solutions seen elsewhere, looked a bit clumsy, but the solution from [Josh Jordan on How to call base.base](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2323401/how-to-call-base-base-method) was quite useful.

However we followed the approach below (which I see now is very similar to what Dan Abramov propose).

```
public class Base
{
    public virtual void Foo()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello from Base");
    }
}

public class Derived : Base
{
    public override void Foo()
    {
        base.Foo();
        Console.WriteLine("Text 1");
        WriteText2Func();
        Console.WriteLine("Text 3");
    }

    protected virtual void WriteText2Func()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Text 2");
    }
}

public class Special : Derived
{
    public override void WriteText2Func()
    {
        //WriteText2Func will write nothing when method Foo is called from class Special.
        //Also it can be modified to do something else.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

All these strong opinions...

Sometimes it just makes sense to use 99% of something...

```
public class Base
{
  public virtual void Foo()
  {
   // Do something
  }
}

public class DerivedLevel1 : Base
{
  public override void Foo()
  {
    DerivedLevel1Foo();
  }
  protected void DerivedLevel1Foo()
  {
    // Do something
    base.Foo();
  }
}

public class DerivedLevel2 : DerivedLevel1
{
  public override void Foo()
  {
   DerivedLevel2Foo();
  }
  protected void DerviedLevel2Foo()
  {
    // Do something
    base.Foo();
  }
}

public class Special : Derived
{
  public override void Foo()
  {
    // Don't do DerivedLevel2Foo()
    base.DerivedLevel1Foo();
  }
}
```