# Calling the grand-parent implementation of an overridden method

Tags: c#, inheritance

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to call base.base.method()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2323401/how-to-call-base-base-method)

I have some trouble with Inheritance in C#. I've sketched three classes: `A`, `B` and `C`. `C` inherits from `B` and `B` from `A`. Now the `B` class calls `base.Method1` and works fine but I can't call `A.method1` from the `C` class. If I call `base.Method1` from `C` obviously that method will be `method1` of `B`. Any advice?

P.S. in `A` class there are some fields marked private so you can access them only

```
class A
{    
    private instance;    
    public virtual void Method1 ()
    {       
        instance = this;
        do something;       
    }
}

class B : A
{
    public override void Method1()
    {
        base.Method1();
        do something;       
    }
}

class C : B
{   
    public override void Method1 ()
    {
        //need A Method1 then do something
    }
}
```

Comment: why would you want to do that? If you describe your problem it will be easier to help you.

Comment: Well maybe then you should be more interested in `C : A` then !

Comment: While .net allows this, C# does not. And it's a bad idea anyways.

Comment: `A c = new C(); c.Method1();` this calls `A.Method1()` but when you say `C c = new C(); c.Method1();` it calls `C.Method1()`

Comment: @Codes: A comment on an answer on the question I linked suggests that it's no longer possible to do this in .NET - do you know whether it is or not? (I'll readily admit I have no idea, I'm just curious.)

Comment: @Rawling I think calling grand-parents is still possible, calling them on classes that aren't your ancestors isn't. There are some weird binary compatibility scenarios related to this.

Comment: @mahditahsildari I'm not sure exactly what you mean, but since `Method1` is _virtual_, the same implementation is called in both cases. Maybe your comment would be more relevant if `Method1` was `new` in the derived class, instead of `override`.

Comment: @MahdiTahsildari `A c = new C(); c.Method1(); this calls A.Method1()` -- to reinforce what Jeppe said, no, it doesn't, and that's the whole point of polymorphism and virtual functions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a feature of C#. If you wish to expose this method to class C, consider refactoring A like so:

```
class A
{    
  private instance;    
  public virtual void Method1 ()
  {
    AMethod1();       
  }

  protected void AMethod1()
  {
    instance = this;
    do something;       
  }
}
```

This will enable you to call this method from within C:

```
class C : B
{   
  public override void Method1 ()
  {
    AMethod1();
    // do something;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this was the fastest and simple solution :D

Answer (score 4):

It is not possible to do this in C#, thought its possible to do this via IL.

For your case, you may do something like this:

```
class A
{
    private int instance;
    public virtual void Method1()
    {
        Method1Impl();
    }

    protected void Method1Impl()
    {
    }
}
```

Now you can call `A.Method1Impl` from your C class.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot skip directly to `A` using `base.Method1`, because that's just for the one above. However, you can use a protected delegate or reference to A to make a direct call. Make a protected field `Action _A_Method1` and in the constructor of `A`, set it to `Method1` (`_A_Method1 = Method1`). Now you can use a direct call to that from class `C` (`_A_Method1();`).

Comment: You can enclose inline code between backticks `, so it gets formatted as code

Comment: That's clever, though clunky.

Comment: The problem with this is, if _A_Method1() is virtual, you will get a stack overflow exception.

Comment: So you might as well have a protected BaseMethod() and have _A_Method1() call BaseMethod().  Then, in your grandchild, you can just call BaseMethod() in _A_Method1()..  And the parent, you can override _A_Method1() and do what it wants.