# Is there a way to call super's super in C#

Tags: c#, polymorphism, radix

I know it's crappy design, I'm just kinda lazy to overhaul the code, I'd rather take a shortcut.

```
class Grandma
{
   public virtual void Mtd(){}
}

class Mommy : Grandma
{
   public override void Mtd(){ base.Mtd(); /* other stuff I wanna skip*/}
}

class Daughter : Mommy
{
   public override void Mtd(){ /*base.base.Mtd() //How can I do it ? */}
}
```

Because the method is virtual upcast won't work. So, is that even possible?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to call base.base.method()?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2323401/how-to-call-base-base-method)

Answer (score 4):

It's not possible; however, if you want to take a shortcut, you could just add a type check within your `Mommy` method:

```
class Mommy : Grandma
{
    public override void Mtd()
    { 
        base.Mtd();   // calls `Grandma` implementation

        if (this.GetType() == typeof(Mommy))
        {
            // not executed for any derived class
        }

        if (!(this is Daughter))
        {
            // not executed for `Daughter`
        }
    }        
}

class Daughter : Mommy
{
    public override void Mtd()
    { 
        base.Mtd();   // calls `Mommy` implementation
    }
}
```

Comment: But that would make the Mommy class tightly coupled with the Daughter class, which I think is bad practice ;)

Comment: I've added an alternative check of `this.GetType() == typeof(Mommy)` that would exclude all derived classes, not just `Daughter`. Of course, this remains, as you requested, a "hack"; the proper solution would probably be to refactor your code (either by introducing a boolean parameter, or by splitting the method hierarchy).

Answer (score 3):

It isn't possible to 'skip' the `Mommy` override.
You'll have to refactor it somehow.