# Calling a super base class method from a derived class C#

Tags: c#, inheritance, derived-class, base-class

I am trying to call a Super base class method from a derived class

```cs
public class Base
{
    public virtual void TestFun()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("This is Class Base");
    }
}

public class A : Base
{
    public override void TestFun()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("This is Class A");

        base.TestFun();
    }
}

public class B : A
{
    public override void TestFun()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("This is Class B");

        base.TestFun();
    }
}

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Base obj = new B();

        obj.TestFun();
    }
}
```

I am getting the output as

1. This is Class B
2. This is Class A
3. This is Class Base

I want to know how can we skip calling the function in A. That means I want to call class "Base" function from class "B"

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to call base.base.method()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2323401/how-to-call-base-base-method)

Comment: @asaf92, Thank you for the response. I cannot alter the code in second layer (ie class A). do we have anyother provision ?

Comment: Calling a superbase class is not a good practice. Can you please let us know why do you want to do that?

Comment: _"I want to know how can we skip calling the function in A. That means I want to call class "Base" function from class "B""_ If you have the urge to do that, then your inheritance tree is wrong. Given the comment you cannot change `A`, you probably need to extend `Base` directly.

Comment: TL;DR; You can, but you really shouldn't.

Comment: @HariSankar Yes, refactor your code