# How to override an overridden method which calls the base method

Tags: c#, inheritance

I have a method `Hello` in class `A`, which should be overridden by class `B`.
Therefore the overridden method in `B` has to call the base method to prepare something.

The method `DoSomeThing` is the additional functionality of this method. Now I want to override `B.Hello` in the new class `C` in order to change logic of `B.DoSomeThing`.

Requirements:

- `C.Hello` needs the method call of `A.Hello`, too, in order to do some basic preparations
- Only `B.DoSomeThing` should be replaced width new functionality, defined in `C.DoSomeThing2`
- I am not allowed to change code inside `A` and `B`

```
public class A 
{
   protected virtual void Hello() {}
}

public class B : A 
{
   protected override void Hello() {
      base.Hello();

      DoSomeThing();
   }
}

public class C : B 
{
   protected override void Hello() {
      ???????????????

      DoSomeThing2();
   }
}
```

I cannot call the base method of class `A`. What would be the best solution for my problem?

Simply copy and paste the code of `A.Hello` wouldn't work because of private methods in `A`.

**EDIT:** class `C` has to inherit from class `B`.

Comment: Can you not inherit from class A directly and after calling the base method, write your own logic of DoSomething?

Comment: I have to inherit from B, because I need the methods and logic.

Comment: So you need all the functionality of A, partial functionality of B and some new functionality of C without touching the class B, seems impossible to me.

Comment: Sounds like your inheritance tree is broken. Try to refactor to Composition over Inheritance. As is, your requirements contradict each other, given that C _must_ inherit B, not A.

Comment: One way to do this is using reflection. However this is neither good style, nor performant. See Evk's answer to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2323401/how-to-call-base-base-method

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to call base.base.method()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2323401/how-to-call-base-base-method)

Comment: @Đøharrrck When you made a mess, you clean it up, don't make it worse.

Comment: Right, that's why I wrote that this isn't good style. However, it is technically a possible solution for the question, especially if the author of class C doesn't have control over the source code of classes A and B and cannot clean up.