# Is there a way to specify scope?

Tags: c#, inheritance, scope

Consider this code sample:

```
public abstract class Parent
{
    public int val;
    public Parent()
    {
        val = 0;
    }
    public virtual void foo()
    {
        inc();
    }

    public virtual void inc()
    {
        val = val + 10;
    }
}

public class Child : Parent
{
    public override void foo()
    {
        base.foo();
    }

    public override void inc()
    {
        val++;
    }
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Parent p = new Child();
    Console.WriteLine("p.val = " + p.val);  //Output: p.val = 0
    p.foo();
    Console.WriteLine("P.val = " + p.val);  //Output: p.val = 1
}
```

I am assuming the `inc()` of the Parent class did not get called because `{this}` pointer is actually pointing to a Child object so the Child's version of `inc()` will be called from the Parent object's function `foo()`. Is there a way to force the Parent's function `foo()` to always call parent's function  `inc()` Like you could in C++ with `::` operator?

Comment: What if Parent.inc() is not declared as "virtual"?

Comment: Isn't this defeating the whole point of having a polymorphic foo() ? Even if you did Parent::foo() { this.inc() } it will still call Child::foo

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can do it with reflection. And of course the `base` keyword, which doesn't support everything C++'s `::` supports.

Comment: Your question is "I want non-virtual dispatch of a virtual function". If non-virtual dispatch is what you want then *why did you mark it as virtual in the first place?*

Comment: Please don't prefix your titles with "C#" and such. That's what the tags are for.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're over-thinking the problem.

- If you want non-virtual dispatch then *don't make the methods virtual in the first place*.
- If you want both virtual and non-virtual dispatch then *make two methods, one virtual and one static*

For example:

```
class Base
{
    protected static void NonVirtualFoo(Base b)
    {
        // Whatever
    }
    public virtual void Foo()
    {
        Base.NonVirtualFoo(this);
    }
}

class Derived : Base
{
    protected new static void NonVirtualFoo(Derived d)
    {
        // Whatever
    }
    public override void Foo()
    {
        Derived.NonVirtualFoo(this);
        Base.NonVirtualFoo(this);
    }
}
```

Use the right tool for the job. If you want virtual dispatch then **call a virtual method**.  If you want static dispatch then **call a static method**. Don't try to take a hammer to a virtual method and make it statically dispatched; that's working against the entire purpose of the tool.

Answer (score 7):

No, the only way you can call a virtual method non-virtually is with `base.Foo`. Of course, you could write a *non-virtual* method in `Parent`, and make `Parent.foo()` call that, as well as the default implementation of `Parent.inc()`.

Answer (score 1):

The Child instance will call its own type implementation.

`foo()` calls `base.foo()` and `base.foo()` calls `inc()`, which in this case `inc()` is from the Child, since the instance is Child type, and will use this implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it is actually possible [as said here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4358250/870604):

This does the trick:

```
public abstract class Parent
{
    public int val;

    public Parent()
    {
        val = 0;
    }

    public virtual void foo()
    {
        MethodInfo method = typeof(Parent).GetMethod("inc");
        DynamicMethod dm = new DynamicMethod("BaseInc", null, new Type[] { typeof(Parent) }, typeof(Parent));
        ILGenerator gen = dm.GetILGenerator();
        gen.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_1);
        gen.Emit(OpCodes.Call, method);
        gen.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);

        var BaseInc = (Action<Parent>)dm.CreateDelegate(typeof(Action<Parent>));
        BaseInc(this);
    }

    public virtual void inc()
    {
        val = val + 10;
    }
}
```

But it's only a *proof of concept*: it's **horrible** and **totally breaks the polymorphism**.

I don't think you can have a valid reason to write this.

Comment: Is it really necessary to use codegen and not just use normal reflection with `method.Invoke(this, null)`?

Comment: @svick Yes. `method.Invoke(this, null)` would call the overriden `inc` method.