# Check if object implements a specific generic interface

Tags: c#

**Background**

My code base currently has the following interfaces and classes:

```cs
// Both DisplayValue _classes_
public class DisplayValue<T>
{
    public T Value { get; set; }
}
public class DisplayValue : DisplayValue<object> {}

// Both IValueWidget _interfaces_
public interface IValueWidget<T>
{
    DisplayValue<T> Value { get; set; }
}
public interface IValueWidget: IValueWidget<object>
{
    new DisplayValue Value { get; set; }
}

// the BaseWidget all other widgets implement
public interface IBaseWidget
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

The code base also has a bunch of Widgets, all of which implement `IBaseWidget`. Some also implement `IValueWidget` or `IValueWidget<T>`, which leads me to my problem.

**Problem**

Say I have the following method:

```cs
public T2 DoStuff<T2>(T2 widget) where T2 : IBaseWidget
{
    // this should check if the widget is the correct type
    if (widget is IValueWidget)
    {
    }
}
```

In that method, I would like to have the condition work with either `IValueWidget` or *any* generic version of `IValueWidget`. I don't care whatsoever what the type of `T` is, only that the given `T2` can be treated as such.

Also worth mentioning, literally no types other than the ones provided above are known at compile time. Everything must work at runtime.

In Java, I could do something like this but obviously C# does not have wildcards.

```java
public T2 DoStuff<T2 extends IBaseWidget>(T2 widget) {
    if (widget instanceof IValueWidget<?>) {
    }
}
```

**Notes**

As far as I can tell, this is not actually a duplicate. Please don't flag it as such if you're referring to any of these, as they are similar but definitely *not* the same:

- [Check if object implements specific generic interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31938956/)
- [Wildcard equivalent in C# generics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15574977/)
- [Get interfaces implemented by class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52758745/)

Comment: What about the answer present here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/503359/6757825

Comment: I'm confused. Why are you checking for IBaseWidget at all when you want to test if it's ALSO implementing IValueWidget, and those two interfaces are not related...?

Comment: `IValueWidget` implements `IValueWidget<T>`, so what you're really asking is whether the `IValueWidget<T>` interface is implemented, regardless of the type parameter `T` used. See duplicate...it answers exactly what you're asking.