# Invoke an overridden instance method using reflection in java

Tags: java, reflection

I would like to do this: [Use reflection to invoke an overridden base method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4357729/use-reflection-to-invoke-an-overridden-base-method)
 but

- have it done in java
- and when @Override has not been specified on the child method (this is for when I don't have access to the source)

I have:

---

```
package test;

public class A{
  public String toString(){
    return "A";
  }
}
```

---

```
package test;

public class B extends A{
  public String toString(){
    return "B";
  }
}
```

---

I want `((A)(new B())).toString()` to be "A", not "B". Is there a way to get this using reflection?

Comment: Cool. Start writing some code. And if you have a question, come back here. @Overriden is irrelevant to the problem, BTW.

Comment: You've got a problem @zcaudate. The `@Override` annotation is an annotation that does not appear in the compiled bytecode. It is a compile time language feature.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MethodHandles can be used to invoke a superclass method:

https://www.baeldung.com/java-method-handles

Answer (score 1):

Your challenge (I want `((A)(new B())).toString()` to be "A", not "B".)  has nothing to do with reflection at all. even if you execute `((A)(new B())).toString()` in your java program without reflection, it will always print "B". Reason for this is that both classes A and B override the `toString()` method, at runtime the real object type will be determined and the `toString()` method of that type/class will be called. So in your example: you create an instance of B, so real object type is B! then you upcast to A, so reference type will be A now, but the referenced, "real" object type will remain B!

https://www.programcreek.com/2009/02/overriding-and-overloading-in-java-with-examples/

Comment: see the c# example linked in the question.