# Is there a java equivalent of System.activator.createinstance?

Tags: java, .net

Is there a way to generate a late binding object in java the way that .Net does it?

Comment: This is ridiculous. Do you guys even know what the .net activator does?

Comment: Can you guys please reopen this question. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4357729/use-reflection-to-invoke-an-overridden-base-method for its usage.