# How to test a virtual method defined in an abstract class?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, testing

I need to unit-test a virtual method defined in an abstract class. But the base class is abstract, so I can't create an instance of it. What do you recommend me to do?

This is a follow up to the following question: [I am thinking about if it is possible to test via an instance of a subclass of the abstract class. Is it a good way? How can I do it?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44400923/156458)

Comment: Your test can itself have a test class which inherits from the abstract class.  Then the test can instantiate an instance of that and test the functionality.  It's a bit more of an "arrange" step, but still a valid one I would think.

Comment: I agree with @David here.

Answer (score 5):

I'm not sure what your abstract class looks like, but if you have something like:

```
public abstract class SomeClass
{
    public abstract bool SomeMethod();

    public abstract int SomeOtherMethod();

    public virtual int MethodYouWantToTest()
    {
        // Method body
    }
}
```

And then, as @David suggested in the comments:

```
public class Test : SomeClass
{
    // You don't care about this method - this is just there to make it compile
    public override bool SomeMethod()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    // You don't care about this method either
    public override int SomeOtherMethod()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    // Do nothing to MethodYouWantToTest
}
```

Then you just instantiate `Test` for your unit test:

```
[TestClass]
public class UnitTest1
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestMethod1()
    {
        SomeClass test = new Test();
        // Insert whatever value you expect here
        Assert.AreEqual(10, test.MethodYouWantToTest());
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Where is `MethodYouWantToTest` called in teh test class?

Comment: @Tim I included an example of that - you can just instantiate `Test` and use it like you were using the abstract class (which is why you don't want to override `MethodYouWantToTest` in the `Test` class - that way you know that you're running the code from the base class).

Answer (score 4):

There's no rule that says a unit test can't define its own classes.  This is a fairly common practice (at least for me anyway).

Consider the structure of a standard unit test:

```
public void TestMethod()
{
    // arrange
    // act
    // assert
}
```

That "arrange" step can include any reasonable actions (without side-effects outside of the test) which set up what you're trying to test.  This can just as easily include creating an instance of a class whose sole purpose is to run the test.  For example, something like this:

```
private class TestSubClass : YourAbstractBase { }

public void TestMethod()
{
    // arrange
    var testObj = new TestSubClass();

    // act
    var result = testObj.YourVirtualMethod();

    // assert
    Assert.AreEqual(123, result);
}
```