# How to build an expression equivalent of base.ToString()

Tags: c#

How can I build an `Expression`object (`Expression.Call`) that will do the equivalent of calling `base.ToString()` on an object ?

My answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62216672/460084) shows how to create a delegate to call the base version of an overriden virtual method given a derived instance.

What I am trying to do is to convert that answer into Expression form.
Here is where I got so far:

```
var o = Expression.Parameter(typeof(object), "o");
var toStringMethodInfo = type.BaseType.GetMethod("ToString");
var ftn = toStringMethodInfo.MethodHandle.GetFunctionPointer();
ConstructorInfo ctorInfo = typeof(Func<string>).GetConstructor(new Type[] { type, typeof(IntPtr) });
var baseToStringExp = Expression.New(ctorInfo, o, Expression.Constant(ftn));
var baseToStringInvokedExp = Expression.Invoke(e, new Expression[] { });
```

I then create a `lambda o => baseToStringInvokedExp`, compile it and try it with an instance of a derived class, but I get an endless loop.

EDIT

Seems like above code works fine and the problem is elsewhere in my program

Comment: I think the only option is to go with reflection emit

Comment: Like here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4357729/use-reflection-to-invoke-an-overridden-base-method

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Use reflection to invoke an overridden base method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4357729/use-reflection-to-invoke-an-overridden-base-method)

Comment: I will see if I can turn this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/14415506/460084 into an expression

Answer (score 1):

Your code snippet looks good. Perhaps you were applying it incorrectly? Here is an example on how to use that Expression on a sample object.

```cs
using System.Linq.Expressions;
using System.Reflection;

void InvokeToStringMethodOnBaseClass<T>(T testObject)
{
    Type type = typeof(T);

    var input = Expression.Parameter(typeof(object), "input");
    var toStringMethodInfo = type.BaseType!.GetMethod("ToString");
    var ftn = toStringMethodInfo!.MethodHandle.GetFunctionPointer();
    ConstructorInfo ctorInfo = typeof(Func<string>).GetConstructor(new Type[] { type, typeof(IntPtr) })!;
    var baseToStringExp = Expression.New(ctorInfo, input, Expression.Constant(ftn));
    var baseToStringInvokedExp = Expression.Invoke(baseToStringExp, Array.Empty<Expression>());

    // Writing it to the console output for demonstration
    var writeln = Expression.Call(typeof(Console).GetMethod("WriteLine", new[] { typeof(string) })!, baseToStringInvokedExp);
    var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Action<T>>(writeln, input);
    var compiled = lambda.Compile();
    compiled(testObject);
}
```

If you then have some sample classes

```cs
class BaseClass
{
    public override string ToString() => "Base String";
}

class DerivedClass : BaseClass
{
    public override string ToString() => "Derived String";
}
```

you can invoke your expressions like this

```cs
InvokeToStringMethodOnBaseClass(new DerivedClass()); // writes "Base String" to console
```