# Storing references to an object in DataTable using the "this" keyword

Tags: c#, ado.net, reference, datatable

I have a collection of objects with no key or order or other obvious index.

I wish to store data regarding each object in a DataTable. I thought an elegant way of doing this would be to store a reference in the owner column, and make that columns type `typeof(MyClass)`.

However, when I try to do this in practice, it doesn't work (it says the primary keys collide). Turns out that putting the instances into a row field just writes "`MyProgram.MyClass`" into the field - presumably the output of `toString` even though that row's type was supposed to be `MyClass` not `string`.

Here is some sample code which works in LINQPad:

```
void Main()
{
    // Create a table
    var table = new DataTable();

    var ownerColumn = new DataColumn("Owner", typeof(MyClass));

    var primaryKey = new[] { ownerColumn };

    table.Columns.AddRange(primaryKey);
    table.PrimaryKey = primaryKey;

    table.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Some Data", typeof(int)) { DefaultValue = 0 });

    // Create 2 objects
    var c1 = new MyClass();
    var c2 = new MyClass();

    // Store their data in the table
    var row = table.NewRow();
    row["Owner"] = c1;
    row["Some Data"] = 1;
    table.Rows.Add(row);

    row = table.NewRow();
    row["Owner"] = c2;
    row["Some Data"] = 2;
    table.Rows.Add(row);
}

// Define other methods and classes here
class MyClass {

}
```

What do I do to solve this? Do I have to make an `id` field in `MyClass`, then use `id` to fill in the owner column, and then make sure each object receives a unique `id` at creation myself?

Comment: Are you sure that the code does not work? Looking at the .NET code there is no reason why this would not work. What is the output of `row["Owner"].GetType()`?

Comment: @Knaģis It's `typeof (MyClass)`. Also, it throws an exception in LinqPad and unless I'm mistaken compiled C# code as well.

Comment: ok, so the requirement was to use MyClass as the primary key for the DataTable?

Comment: @Knaģis I think so. I was trying to use references to instances of `MyClass` as the key, so that there can not be two rows pointing to the same object.

Comment: Added a new answer describing what is needed to use `MyClass` as the primary key.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to implement `System.IComparable` (non-generic version) interface on `MyClass` so that `DataTable` knows how to to compare the value of the column. If this interface is not defined, the code falls back on comparing object.ToString() results.

Comment: Thanks, that works! But with the thing I am trying to program, it is illogical for MyClass instances to have a "sort order". I implemented the method as `public int CompareTo(object other) { return other == this ? 0 : 1; }` but is there a less hacky way? It seems implementing IEquatable doesn't work.

Comment: I would advise of implementing the IComparable so that it returns a deterministic sort order, for example, using `return other == this ? 0 : this.GetHashCode().CompareTo(other.GetHashCode())` (just remember to check for null-s. The reason is that some collections actually check if the CompareTo results are meaningful (for example, checks `if a > b then b must be < a`.

Comment: Thanks, I hadn't thought of nulls or hash codes. The problem in my question is resolved at this point, however, I think with your version two objects can be evaluated equal if their hashes collide (different objects -> checks hash -> hashes happen to be the same -> hash comparison returns 0 anyway). My intention is that `MyClass.CompareTo` returns 0 if *and only if* the two references point to the same place, and not to merely objects with equal hashes.

Comment: Nevermind, I was able to find a satisfactory hash function (and in fact I think the default implementation is also satisfactory): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1139767/object-gethashcode

Answer (score 1):

You can use auto increment column :

```
DataTable dTable = new DataTable();
DataColumn auto = new DataColumn("AutoID", typeof(System.Int32));
dTable.Columns.Add(auto);
auto.AutoIncrement = true;
auto.AutoIncrementSeed = 1;
auto.ReadOnly = true;
```

Comment: I'm not sure but won't this lead to problems with normalization? Specifically, it will become possible for me to have two rows with different "AutoID" values but the same "Owner", unless I make both of them primary keys in which key my primary key will become redundant. (I made a separate question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13233088/normalize-a-table-with-a-two-column-primary-key-and-one-other-column)