# Normalize a table with a two-column primary key and one other column

Tags: c#, database-design, ado.net, datatable, database-normalization

My `DataTable` has 3 columns: A, B and C. None are guaranteed to have unique entries, in non-trivial cases every column will have non-unique entries.

The combination of {A, B} *is* guaranteed to be unique. Because ADO.NET `DataTable` allows using multiple columns as the primary key, I use A and B as my primary key.

A vs B represents a matrix with 0 as the default value, so it's possible for me to guarantee that entries of B will come from a finite pool and for each entry of A, every possible {A, B} will appear (ie such that there will be exactly `number of unique A values * number of unique B values` rows in the table).

My question has two parts:

1) How to normalize this so that I have one key and no update anomalies (I'm not sure but I think I want a [3NF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Third_normal_form))? (Unless I am mistaken, simply adding an extra "ID" column with non-redundant integers will allow update anomalies)

2) How to set it up (in C# using the ADO.NET library) so that whenever I want to add a row, I specify entries of B and C, and then it automatically generates a suitable value of A, so that I can "insert C at {A, B}"? A can be an integer or a string.

The two are related, since your answer for 2 may affect 1 and vice versa.

Comment: You will not learn by getting others to do your homework.

Comment: @ChrisBint why do you consider it homework?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `DataColumn.Expression` property to automatically generate value for a column based on the values of other columns.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumn.expression.aspx

Answer (score 1):

A key doesn't have to be a single column to satisfy 3NF. It can be multiple columns - in this example (A,B) - or as in the example in the wikipedia link you've given.

However if you want to have a single column key, then you can create a new column with an autogenerated ID (eg: `IDENTITY(1,1)` in SQL server), and create a unique index on columns (A,B)