# Loop over data object of strings construction of a unique distinct collection

Tags: c#, string, performance, recursion, collections

i don't know how but for weeks now i was using a `HashSet<myObject>` collection of mainly strings members as i really  though it's internally uses a builtin approach as dictionary to avoid duplicate items in a non KVP format of data(single columns)

my scenario is :

```
HashSet<myHddFolderPaths> UniqColleciton = new HashSet<myHddFolderPtahs>
int countRounds=0;
void addToCollection()
{

    for(int i=0, i < UniqColleciton.Count; i++)
    {
        add some items to UniqColleciton via Directory.GetDirectories();
    }
    if(countRounds++ < Limit)  
       addToCollection()
}
```

this is a pattern for dir-walker i am building and this is only an example for a scenario when recurse of same data could not be avoided so i don't recall where i have read about it and thought, that by simply using a `HashSet<T>` would "just take Care of business"

i haven't thought of the option it will allow duplicates but in this project i put it to a test and it did allow to my surprise to add an existing items 
so my work around is :

```
Dictionary<string, int> fiterAccesDeniedPaths = new Dictionary<string, int>();
Dictionary<string, int> fiterAccesiblePaths = new Dictionary<string, int>();

if (this.fiterAccesDeniedPaths.ContainsKey(e.Message)) continue;
if (this.fiterAccessiblePaths.ContainsKey(object.stringPathMember)) continue;
add to filters ; UniqColleciton.Add(myHddFolderPaths);
```

**is there a better/more efficient approach for acomplishing this task ?**

```
public class FolderPath
{
    public string DriveL { get; set; }
    public string FolderLevel { get; set; }
    public string Path { get; set; }
    public int Fsize { get; set; }
}


    public class GenericUniqCollectionM<T> : HashSet<T>
    {
        public GenericUniqCollectionM():base()
        {

        }
    }
```

Comment: What is `myHddFolderPaths`? Your own class I guess, could you post the code.

Comment: @IvanStoev sure thing give me a Minute.

Comment: @IvanStoev do i need to implement it on my object or on the collection, i will now add another code for the `MyUniqCollection<T>`

Comment: Nevermind, see the @Arie answer. But if you need multiple unique constrains/indexes, multi dictionary approach is just fine, but then no need of `HashSet`, you can use just list. Of course all this should be encapsulated in a custom collection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `HashSet` created with the parameterless constructor uses a default equality comparer. The [default comparer](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/generic/equalitycomparer.cs,ac282b3e1817bb9b) will use `FolderPath.Equals()` to check equality.

```
internal class ObjectEqualityComparer<T> : EqualityComparer<T>
{
    public override bool Equals(T x, T y)
    {
        if (x != null)
        {
            if (y != null) return x.Equals(y);
            return false;
        }
        if (y != null) return false;
        return true;
    }

    public override int GetHashCode(T obj)
    {
        if (obj == null) return 0;
        return obj.GetHashCode();
    }

    ...
}
```

You didn't override `Equals` and `GetHashCode`, so it will use the default implementation provided by `object`, checking reference equality.

You have two options now. One is to override `Equals` and `GetHashCode` in `FolderPath`.

```
public class FolderPath
{
    ...

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        if (obj == null) return false;

        FolderPath other = obj as FolderPath;
        if (other == null) return false;

        //simple implementation, only compares Path
        return Path == other.Path;
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        if (Path == null) return 0;
        return Path.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

The other one is to implement a custom `IEqualityComparer<FolderPath>`

```
public class FolderPathComparer : IEqualityComparer<FolderPath>
{
    public bool Equals(FolderPath x, FolderPath y)
    {
        if (x != null)
        {
            if (y != null) return x.Path == y.Path;
            return false;
        }
        if (y != null) return false;
        return true;
    }

    public int GetHashCode(FolderPath obj)
    {
        if (obj == null || obj.Path == null) return 0;
        return obj.Path.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

and pass it to the `HashSet` constructor.

```
var set = new HashSet<FolderPath>(new FolderPathComparer());
```

Comment: i have made an edit to my question could you please implement the important part of your code on `GenericUniqCollectionM` as a sample?

Comment: so now on this implementation if i add to any of my classes > `MycustomObject : ObjectEqualityComparer` this should do the job ?

Comment: i was in too busy i forgot  to thank you it really solved my approach using an wkward solution with dictionary filters. thank you very much Mr Lortz

Comment: @JbobJohan You're welcome. You accepted the answer - that's already considered a 'thank you'.

Answer (score 1):

Ypu wanted your `HashSet` to "take care of business". `HashSet` does exactly that. But you first have to let it know what you consider a "duplicate" (or rather when your objects should be considered equal). To do so, you should implement (override) `GetHashCode()` method on your `myHddFolderPaths` class.

[How does HashSet compare elements for equality?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8952003/how-does-hashset-compare-elements-for-equality)

[Implementing GetHashCode correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9009760/implementing-gethashcode-correctly)

[Default implementation for Object.GetHashCode()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/720177/default-implementation-for-object-gethashcode/720282#720282)