# When to use a GUID for a class

Tags: c#, generic-list, gethashcode

I'm working on a simple application with a few classes. This all started when I wanted to use the [`Remove`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cd666k3e) method on a `List<Car>`. This method requires that you override the `Equals` and the `GetHashCode` methods for the `Car` type. In this situation, I decided to implement an ID property on the `Car` class. That way, my `Equals` method simply checks for ID equality, and my `GetHashCode` method returns `base.GetHashCode()`.

Is this a good approach, or is implementing a GUID for a small class too heavy-handed? There wouldn't be any need for it without the reasons I explained above. The only requirement for uniqueness for this Car type is that it be unique within the `List<T>` collection to which it belongs. But adding the GUID property seemed like the quickest way around the `GetHashCode` mess. BTW, there are no int properties on my Car type.

Comment: Just to clarify, the `Remove` method doesn't require the overrides, by default it uses [`EqualityComparer<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cd666k3e.aspx).

Comment: That's helpful Adam, thanks; I was just using the default implementation, but it wasn't removing any of the objects in the list. So I started reading and found some materials that made it sound like you needed to override Equals(), which then required you to override GetHashCode().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of implementing Equals and GetHashCode just use [`RemoveAll`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wdka673a.aspx):

```
myList.RemoveAll(x => x.ID == myCar.ID);
```

This allows you to specify a predicate that indicates what items should be removed instead (it doesn't matter that you are only removing one item).

---

Implementing `Equals` and `GetHashCode` in the way you describe strikes me as extremely dodgey - if your `Equals` implementation returns `true` then your `GetHashCode` method **needs** to return the same value so that those two objects will be placed in the same bucket in a hashtable.  Your implementation (as I understand it) doesn't match this criteria as the base `GetHashCode` implementation is almost certainly going to return different values for two `Car` instances, regardless of if they have the same ID or not.

Implementing `Equals` and `GetHashCode` isn't entirely trivial and is probably something I'd generally avoid doing if there are alternatives.  If you really want to do this then take a look at these resoruces:

- [What is the best algorithm for an overridden System.Object.GetHashCode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/263400/what-is-the-best-algorithm-for-an-overridden-system-object-gethashcode)
- [Default implementation for Object.GetHashCode()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/720177/default-implementation-for-object-gethashcode/720282#720282).
- [implementing the Equals method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/336aedhh%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Also hash codes are not [GUIDs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Globally_unique_identifier)

Comment: Which part of my question suggested that I thought a hashcode was a guid?

Comment: @AndrewBSchultz "Is this a good approach, or is implementing a GUID for a small class too heavy-handed?", also the Title :)

Comment: OK. I know a GUID isn't a hash code. The GUID was meant to be used in the Equals() implementation, and the GetHashCode() override was, in my mind, simply a requirement that grew out of overriding the Equals() method. I used base.GetHashCode because I didn't know how to construct an int that would be unique from my properties - that's why I said "there are not int properties on my car type."

Comment: @AndrewBSchultz See the answer for "What is the best algorithm for an overridden System.Object.GetHashCode?", you can combine hash codes from other objects (e.g. strings) to create a unique hash code, e.g. `ID.GetHashCode()` where `ID` is your guid.

Answer (score 3):

> There wouldn't be any need for it without the reasons I explained above.

If your class doesn't *logically* have an ID, then it certainly seems odd to include it just for the sake of equality.

For example, if you have two instances which have equal properties for *everything* apart from ID, are they really non-equal? If they are, you should potentially just use the default implementation of `Equals`/`GetHashCode` which uses reference identity for equality. Where you would use two objects with the same ID, you just use two references to the same object instead.

It really all depends on the context, and you haven't given much of that - but adding an ID *just* for equality is a bit of a design smell.

Comment: Thanks John - what I would do without the ID would be to disallow two objects with equal properties in the same List<Car> collection. But the goal with the List.Remove method would be the following - the list is a property on another type, call it Owner. An instance of Owner and his List<Car> are persisted to storage. Later, they can be retrieved, and one car can be removed. I was using the ID to identify the one to remove, but now that you mention it, reference equality will work for that too, since the caller has to instantiate the list before removing anyway ... thanks for helping me see.