# Comparing two elements on page with selenium getHashCode() function, c#

Tags: javascript, c#, selenium, hashcode

I have two elements on a page that I am grabbing. I am using the selenium getHashCode function to compare the two elements to make sure they are different.

```
  if ((oldQ.GetHashCode() != newQ.GetHashCode())
{
      //Do Something
}
```

Is it dangerous to use the GetHashCode function? I have checked the values and they seem to be unique. These two elements keep changing and I'm not dealing with many elements.

Comment: gethashcode is not guaranteed to define equality - collisions could happen. you should investigate what selenium allows for comparing elements.

Comment: @DanielA.White What is the chance of a collision?

Comment: it depends on the implementation under the covers- since its just an int, theres over 4 billion possibilities.

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11607206/string-gethashcode-uniqueness-and-collisions

Comment: why u use `GetHashCode()` for comparing? I hope this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.comparer.compare?view=net-5.0 helps you

Comment: @DanielA.White Thank you! Also, if both elements have the same text contents, wouldn't they have the same hash?

Comment: not in all cases - what if they are different classes, ids, etc. you have to implement the meaning of equality in this case