# ArgumentException with ListView SelectedItem's property and TextBox binding

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding

**EDIT:**

I figured out that the source of this problem is the `Equals()` and `GetHashCode()` implementation in `Bar`.

Especially the properties (like `Name` in `Bar`) which participates in `GetHashCode()` and is also binded to a `TextBox`. On removing these override methods everything just works fine (except that I want to keep them)

What I don't understand is WHY is this happening??

---

I have a `TextBox`, a `ListView`, and some data bindings with following ViewModel:

```
[PropertyChanged.ImplementPropertyChanged]
public class ViewModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<Foo> Foos { get; set; }

    public Foo SelectedFoo { get; set; }
}

[PropertyChanged.ImplementPropertyChanged]
public class Foo
{
    public Bar FooBar { get; set; }
}

[PropertyChanged.ImplementPropertyChanged]
public class Bar
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        var other = obj as Bar;

        if (other != null)
        {
            return other.Name == Name;
        }

        return false;
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return Name.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

This is my List:

```
<ListView x:Name="V_List" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedFoo}"  ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Foos}" SelectionMode="Single">
    ...
</ListView>
```

And this is my TextBox:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Path=SelectedFoo.FooBar.Name, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus}" />
```

And here's the thing:

When I select the first `Foo` from the `List`, the binding works, and `Name` of the `FooBar` property of selected `Foo` appears in the `TextBox`. No matter how many times I change my selection, the appropriate value appears in the `TextBox`.

But now if I change the `Name` using the `TextBox` (which, after focus lost, because of TwoWay data binding, is working and I checked with Debugging) and then change my selection from the list, the `TextBox` still shows the previously selected item's value.

Moreover, upon selecting that same item again, and then selecting some other item, I get the following exception (which surprisingly, the debugger didn't report, I had to log it to a file. Probably maybe because the exception was not raised from my code.)

Here's the log:

> The Exception is:-Exception :: System.ArgumentException: An item with
>   the same key has already been added.    at
>   System.ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentException(ExceptionResource resource) 
>   at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.Insert(TKey key, TValue
>   value, Boolean add)    at
>   System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2..ctor(IDictionary`2
>   dictionary, IEqualityComparer`1 comparer)    at
>   System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.Selector.InternalSelectedItemsStorage..ctor(InternalSelectedItemsStorage
>   collection, IEqualityComparer`1 equalityComparer)    at
>   System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.Selector.SelectionChanger.ApplyCanSelectMultiple()
>   at System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.Selector.SelectionChanger.End() 
>   at
>   System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.Selector.SetSelectedHelper(Object
>   item, FrameworkElement UI, Boolean selected)    at
>   System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.Selector.NotifyIsSelectedChanged(FrameworkElement
>   container, Boolean selected, RoutedEventArgs e)    at
>   System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.Selector.OnSelected(Object sender,
>   RoutedEventArgs e)    at
>   System.Windows.RoutedEventHandlerInfo.InvokeHandler(Object target,
>   RoutedEventArgs routedEventArgs)    at
>   System.Windows.EventRoute.InvokeHandlersImpl(Object source,
>   RoutedEventArgs args, Boolean reRaised)    at
>   System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEventImpl(DependencyObject sender,
>   RoutedEventArgs args)    at
>   System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEvent(RoutedEventArgs e)    at
>   System.Windows.Controls.ListBoxItem.OnSelected(RoutedEventArgs e)
>   at
>   System.Windows.Controls.ListBoxItem.OnIsSelectedChanged(DependencyObject
>   d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)    at
>   System.Windows.DependencyObject.OnPropertyChanged(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs
>   e)    at
>   System.Windows.FrameworkElement.OnPropertyChanged(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs
>   e)    at
>   System.Windows.DependencyObject.NotifyPropertyChange(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs
>   args)    at
>   System.Windows.DependencyObject.UpdateEffectiveValue(EntryIndex
>   entryIndex, DependencyProperty dp, PropertyMetadata metadata,
>   EffectiveValueEntry oldEntry, EffectiveValueEntry& newEntry, Boolean
>   coerceWithDeferredReference, Boolean coerceWithCurrentValue,
>   OperationType operationType)    at
>   System.Windows.DependencyObject.SetValueCommon(DependencyProperty dp,
>   Object value, PropertyMetadata metadata, Boolean
>   coerceWithDeferredReference, Boolean coerceWithCurrentValue,
>   OperationType operationType, Boolean isInternal)    at
>   System.Windows.DependencyObject.SetCurrentValueInternal(DependencyProperty
>   dp, Object value)    at
>   System.Windows.Controls.ListBox.NotifyListItemClicked(ListBoxItem
>   item, MouseButton mouseButton)    at
>   System.Windows.Controls.ListBoxItem.HandleMouseButtonDown(MouseButton
>   mouseButton)    at
>   System.Windows.Controls.ListBoxItem.OnMouseLeftButtonDown(MouseButtonEventArgs
>   e)    at System.Windows.UIElement.OnMouseLeftButtonDownThunk(Object
>   sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)    at
>   System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs.InvokeEventHandler(Delegate
>   genericHandler, Object genericTarget)    at
>   System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs.InvokeHandler(Delegate handler, Object
>   target)    at
>   System.Windows.RoutedEventHandlerInfo.InvokeHandler(Object target,
>   RoutedEventArgs routedEventArgs)    at
>   System.Windows.EventRoute.InvokeHandlersImpl(Object source,
>   RoutedEventArgs args, Boolean reRaised)    at
>   System.Windows.UIElement.ReRaiseEventAs(DependencyObject sender,
>   RoutedEventArgs args, RoutedEvent newEvent)    at
>   System.Windows.UIElement.OnMouseDownThunk(Object sender,
>   MouseButtonEventArgs e)    at
>   System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs.InvokeEventHandler(Delegate
>   genericHandler, Object genericTarget)    at
>   System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs.InvokeHandler(Delegate handler, Object
>   target)    at
>   System.Windows.RoutedEventHandlerInfo.InvokeHandler(Object target,
>   RoutedEventArgs routedEventArgs)    at
>   System.Windows.EventRoute.InvokeHandlersImpl(Object source,
>   RoutedEventArgs args, Boolean reRaised)    at
>   System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEventImpl(DependencyObject sender,
>   RoutedEventArgs args)    at
>   System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseTrustedEvent(RoutedEventArgs args)    at
>   System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEvent(RoutedEventArgs args, Boolean
>   trusted)    at System.Windows.Input.InputManager.ProcessStagingArea() 
>   at System.Windows.Input.InputManager.ProcessInput(InputEventArgs
>   input)    at
>   System.Windows.Input.InputProviderSite.ReportInput(InputReport
>   inputReport)    at
>   System.Windows.Interop.HwndMouseInputProvider.ReportInput(IntPtr hwnd,
>   InputMode mode, Int32 timestamp, RawMouseActions actions, Int32 x,
>   Int32 y, Int32 wheel)    at
>   System.Windows.Interop.HwndMouseInputProvider.FilterMessage(IntPtr
>   hwnd, WindowMessage msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean&
>   handled)    at
>   System.Windows.Interop.HwndSource.InputFilterMessage(IntPtr hwnd,
>   Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)    at
>   MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam,
>   IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)    at
>   MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DispatcherCallbackOperation(Object o)    at
>   System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate
>   callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)    at
>   System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen(Object source,
>   Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)

Another thing worth mentioning that I noticed is, the exception is not raised if I set the `SelectionMode` of `ListView` to `Multiple`. In that case, the item in `List` whose `FooBar`'s value I changed from the `TextBox`, remains selected, along with any other items that I may select then after.

Note: I am using [Fody/PropertyChanged](https://github.com/Fody/PropertyChanged) to implement `INotifyCollectionChanged`.

Comment: Fody? Well... Why? I don't see any value in it. Anyway.. there are several issues in your VM and view. `Foos` has not been initialised. There is no `SelectedItem` binding for the list view. Why not go back to basics and try to implement a proper MVVM model using INotifyPropertyChanged? Once you know that you can move on to Caliburn.

Comment: @KosalaW Fody is mostly fine as a time saver on boiler plate.  I highly doubt it has anything to do with his issue.

Comment: @KosalaW I may not be an expert yet in implementing MVVM yet, but, I've tried to simplify my code and show here. I can't just copy-paste the exact code here, it's too long and mostly unnecessarily.

Comment: @BrandonKramer Mostly fine?? There are much better ones. The issue that OP is having is very basic. nugets can't solve that problem.

Comment: @KosalaW I agree with BrandonKramer, I don't think Fody is the problem. I just thought people should know about it before tell me to properly implement INotifyPropertyChanged on seeing TwoWay bindings.

Comment: He is not using it to solve the problem, his problem is not related to using Fody, vs doing it the long way.

Comment: @BrandonKramer : So what is OPs problem according to your definition?

Comment: @KosalaW See my answer.

Comment: @KosalaW I happen to agree with you that Caliburn is preferable to Fody, btw.  I just don't believe that Fody is the source of his errors.

Comment: @BrandonKramer : I never said his choice of nuget is the problem. I pointed out pretty much the same thing you have in your answer. My advice was to learn the basic concept before jumping on to some random nuget. When you know the basic, you can use any nuget out of 1m+ nugets to solve your problem. As VijayChavda pointed out, no one knows about all of them. But all WPF devs know about Caliburn, MVVM light etc.

Comment: @KosalaW Fair point.  Apologies for misunderstanding your responses.

Comment: @KosalaW Got your point, Thanks for the advice :)

Comment: @KosalaW Please see the Edit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What I don't understand is WHY is this happening?

I can't give you a definitive answer, but looking at the error, it looks like the ListView is keeping an internal Dictionary of the control's items. Further, I'd bet the key for that internal dictionary is based on the value of GetHashCode. The problem is that you are allowing your users to change that key (by changing the name property) while the object is still part of the control. I'd guess that on selection changing it's maintaining the dictionary by adding and removing items as necessary. Since the effective "key" for your item has changed, it may be trying to readd it to the internal dictionary, only to find that the item is already in the dictionary (but under the original key).

You can test that theory by removing and readding the changed item to the Foos collection when the name changes. That should clear and reinsert the item in the internal dictionary with the correct, new key.

Comment: Yupppp.. Your theory is perfectly right!  When I change the key, it won't allow. However when I change it back, it works fine, which verifies what you just said. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Bar also needs to implement PropertyChanged, if you want Name to be updated.

```
[PropertyChanged.ImplementPropertyChanged]
public class Bar
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Also, it is generally preferable to have the selected item binding done via a property on your VM.

For example:

```
[PropertyChanged.ImplementPropertyChanged]
public class ViewModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<Foo> Foos { get; set; }
    //This is the property to hold the selected item.
    public Foo SelectedFoo { get; set; }
}
```

Then change your ListView binding to:

```
<ListView x:Name="V_List" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedFoo}" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Foos}" SelectionMode="Single">
    ...
</ListView>
```

And your TextBox becomes:

```
<!--No need for binding the DataContext of the Grid.-->
<Grid>
    <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=SelectedFoo.FooBar.Name, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus}" />
</Grid>
```

Comment: Oops.. I missed mention that Bar also implements PropertyChanged. I'll edit the question. I'll try your way now.

Comment: Nope, still the same thing.

Comment: @VijayChavda In that case, your problem is most likely caused by something that you haven't shown us.  You mentioned that your code is quite large, are you certain that there is nothing else in your code that could be affecting this?

Comment: I took good care about it and I'm quite sure. But if you think so, I'll consider checking again.. (hmm.. that might take a while)