# GetHashCode not called from list elements

Tags: c#

I have a simple class, which holds a list of points:

```
public class PointCollection {

    public List<PointModel> list;

    public PointCollection()
    {
        list = new List<PointModel>();
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        int hash = 13;
        hash = (hash * 7) + list.GetHashCode();
        return hash;
    }
}
```

Here's how looks PointModel class:

```
public class PointModel
{
    public float x = 0f;
    public float y = 0f;

    public PointModel()
    {
        x = y = 0;
    }

    public PointModel(float _x, float _y)
    {
        x = _x;
        y = _y;
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        int hash = 13;
        hash = (hash * 7) + x.GetHashCode();
        hash = (hash * 7) + y.GetHashCode();
        return hash;
    }
}
```

However, GetHashCode from PointCollection doesn't work properly. It always returns a different value and GetHashCode from PointModel is never called.

To have this working I have to explicitly iterate through a list and call GetHashCode for each point:

```
public override int GetHashCode()
{
    int hash = 13;
    for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
    {
        hash = (hash * 7) + list[i].GetHashCode();
    }
    return hash;
}
```

Why is that? I have different classes with similar configurations and it works fine, but not in this case.

Comment: [`List<T>`](https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/mscorlib/system/collections/generic/list.cs) doesn't implement `GetHashCode`, so it uses the base implementation: [`Object.GetHashCode()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.object.gethashcode?view=netcore-3.1).  You can see a discussion about this implementation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/720177/default-implementation-for-object-gethashcode).

Comment: Yes, I couldn't find such a question though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`List<>` doesn't override `GetHashCode`, so it will call the base implementation of `Object`.

As you've discovered, if you want to hash the contents on a list you need to iterate over it and do it manually.

If you're a fan of Linq you can calculate the hash using the `Aggregate` method:

```
var hash = list.Aggregate(13, (agg, curr) => (agg * 7) + curr.GetHashCode());
```

Comment: I have a lot of different cases like this (List<SomeClass>) and I thought GetHashCode were called, but it seems like it's not true. So I have to change a lot of GetHashCode implementations. Thanks for the answer and also for the Linq snippet :)